# Google Python style guide

Tags: python

Why does the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) prefer list comprehensions and for loops instead of filter, map, and reduce?

Deprecated Language Features:
 ... "Use list comprehensions and for loops instead of filter, map, and reduce. "

The explanation given : "We do not use any Python version which does not support these features, so there is no reason not to use the new styles."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`map` and `filter` are way less powerful than their list comprehension equivalent. LCs can do both filtering and mapping in one step, they don't require explicit function and can  be compiled more efficiently because of their special syntax

```
# map and filter
map(lambda x:x+1, filter(lambda x:x%3, range(10)))
# same as LC
[x+1 for x in range(10) if x%3]
```

There is simply no reason to prefer map or filter over LCs.

`reduce` is slightly different, because there is no equivalent LC, but it has no big advantage over a ordinary for-loop either.

Comment: The canonical use case where `map()` is still arguably better is applying an existing single argument function to a sequence, such as `map(str, seq)`. That kind of operation is the reason it was eventually retained for Python 3.

Answer (score 35):

The [Google Python Style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) does not say

> prefer list comprehensions and for loops instead of filter, map, and
>   reduce

Rather, the full sentence reads,

> Use list comprehensions and for loops instead of filter and map *when
>   the function argument would have been an inlined lambda anyway*. (my emphasis)

So it is not recommending that you completely avoid using `map`, for instance -- only that

```
[expression(item) for item in iterable]
```

is preferable to

```
map(lambda item: expression(item), iterable)
```

In this case it is clear that the list comprehension is more direct and readable.

On the other hand, there is nothing wrong with using `map` like this:

```
map(str, range(100))
```

instead of the longer-winded

```
[str(item) for item in range(100)]
```

It performs well to boot:

```
In [211]: %timeit list(map(str,range(100)))
7.81 µs ± 151 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [215]: %timeit [str(item) for item in range(100)]
10.3 µs ± 3.06 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: +1 for performance comparison... interesting that map runs faster in this case.

Answer (score 5):

List comprehensions are generally considered more "pythonic" than `filter`, `map` and `reduce`.

See also this [article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) by Python creator Guido van Rossum.

As far as filing this under "Deprecated Language Features" in the style guide, there were apparently plans to deprecate `filter`, `map` and `reduce` in Python 3 (see the [article](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) referenced above).

Some of these plans changed eventually. `reduce` was dropped from being a built-in function (and moved to the `functools` module), but `filter` and `map` are still [available](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html) as built-ins.

Comment: `functools` itself is part of the standard library. The demotion of `reduce()` was actually just making it no longer a builtin.

Answer (score 4):

I would think that it is because not everybody knows how to use those functions well; readability may be impaired for people who are not as familiar. Also, the `for` loop and list comprehension are widely used and easy to understand; even though the latter is from functional programming, just like `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`, it mirrors lists and `for` loops quite well. In any case, cramming a lambda or defining a function just to use with map, filter, or reduce can get annoying, especially since a lambda can only be a single expression and a function could clutter your code. You don't need them anyways; `map(func, seq)` is just `[func(x) for x in seq]` and `filter` is just a list comprehension with an `if` component. `reduce` can be done with a `for` loop.

In short, `for` and list comprehensions are clearer, and they provide basically equivalent functionality in most cases.