# Ignore case in string comparison

Tags: python, equals

If I have two variables, a and b and they could be integers, float, or strings.

I want to return `True` if they are equal (in case of string, ignore case).

As Pythonic as possible.

Comment: .. and what you you tried so far that you could share with us?

Comment: are a and b the same type at the time of comparison?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-python)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the most pythonic I can think of. Better to ask for foregiveness than for permission:

```
>>> def iequal(a, b):
...    try:
...       return a.upper() == b.upper()
...    except AttributeError:
...       return a == b
... 
>>> 
>>> iequal(2, 2)
True
>>> iequal(4, 2)
False
>>> iequal("joe", "Joe")
True
>>> iequal("joe", "Joel")
False
```

Comment: +1. Probably better to use basestring instead of str, but otherwise this seems like exactly what he wants. (Edited to say "jinx, buy me a Coke" to mgilson.)

Comment: sorry, meant to use basestring

Comment: Actually, your try/except variant is probably better than the typecheck anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I hit (+1) as soon as I saw `try/except` :-)

Comment: Agreed - I removed the type check version.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the `except` condition... if the point of this method is to check if a string is equal to something else regardless of case, it should require that the objects at least are valid to be interpreted as strings.  Rather than `return a == b`, maybe `return str(a).upper() == str(b).upper()`, so the caller gets an exception if the test values are not at least string-y.

Comment: @sr2222 but anything can be turned into a string - ``str(3).upper()``

Comment: @sr2222 -- you can convert any object to a string.  Your proposition will never raise an exception.  Plus, then `iequal(1.0,1)` would return `False`, which seems a little funky ...

Comment: First, objects without `__str__`, or a `__str__` that has been intentionally overridden to return an exception, can't be converted to a string.  Second, @mgilson, yes, a method meant to compare 2 strings without case shouldn't evaluate `True` for 2 things that don't have the same string representation with the exception of case.  It's a basic question of functional symmetry.  Third, since calling `upper()` doesn't coerce an object to a string, you could have 2 objects who's string representations are equivalent for which this function would return `False`.

Comment: @sr2222 objects have a default ``__str__`` though: ``class Foo(): pass; x = Foo(); print str(x)`` == ``<__main__.Foo object at 0x108dcec90>``

Comment: @sr2222 -- classes without `__str__` are pretty hard (impossible?) to find.  I'm not even sure how you could manage that ...  second, OP says the input could be "integers, floats, or strings".  While OP is a little vague on the details of how cross-type comparisons should be made, I thought it was worth pointing out where a cross-type comparison would be logical and your proposed solution would yield an unexpected result.

Answer (score 7):

How about this, without isinstance (frowned upon):

```
def equal(a, b):
    try:
        return a.lower() == b.lower()
    except AttributeError:
        return a == b
```

Comment: Python has no `catch` statement.  you're looking for `except`.  But it's best not to have a bare `except` statement.

Comment: Damn, I'm never fast enough.  When I got here there was one answer using isinstance.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Been doing mostly objective c lately.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def equals_ignore_case(a,b):
...   return a.upper() == b.upper()
...
>>> equals_ignore_case("hello","Hello")
True
```