# How to find the length of a "filter" object in python

Tags: python-3.x, filter, variable-length

```
>>> n = [1,2,3,4]

>>> filter(lambda x:x>3,n)
<filter object at 0x0000000002FDBBA8>

>>> len(filter(lambda x:x>3,n))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    len(filter(lambda x:x>3,n))
TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()
```

I could not get the length of the list I got. So I tried saving it to a variable, like this...

```
>>> l = filter(lambda x:x>3,n)
>>> len(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    len(l)
TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()
```

Instead of using a loop, is there any way to get the length of this?

Comment: There is no way to know how many objects a generator will yield before it yields them.  If you care about optimization, you can use _a priori_ information to speed things up - i.e. if you know that your list is sorted you can discard items below `index(3)`.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You have to iterate through the filter object somehow. One way is to convert it to a list:

```
l = list(filter(lambda x: x > 3, n))

len(l)  # <--
```

But that might defeat the point of using `filter()` in the first place, since you could do this more easily with a list comprehension:

```
l = [x for x in n if x > 3]
```

Again, `len(l)` will return the length.

Comment: This is the simpliest way but not really the proper way. I prefer the answer of Al Hoo and tso . What a pity that python didn't internally support the reduce way!

Comment: This solution takes a lot of extra memory if `n` is quite large.

Comment: BEWARE that you cannot do `next(l)` no more cause de filter object has been "used" some how.

Answer (score 34):

This is an old question, but I think this question needs an answer using the **map-reduce** ideology. 
So here:

```
from functools import reduce

def ilen(iterable):
    return reduce(lambda sum, element: sum + 1, iterable, 0)

ilen(filter(lambda x: x > 3, n))
```

This is especially good if `n` doesn't fit in the computer memory.

Comment: Is this faster than using len of a list iteration?

Comment: Not with python, but if you want to optimize some algorithm that needs the length of a filtered object, building a list to count the length is not the optimal way.

Comment: Note that `reduce` was deliberately taken out of the standard library in Python 3.0 and greater. More details about _why_ this was decided can be found here in this thread by Guido van Rossum: https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196

Comment: It seems that reduce it is going to be here for a while. check: https://docs.python.org/3.13/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Answer (score 19):

Converting a filter to a list will take extra memory, which may not be acceptable for large amounts of data. You can find length of the `filter` object without converting it to a `list`:

```py
sum(1 for _ in filter(lambda x: x > 3, n))
```

Answer (score 17):

Generally, `filter` and `reduce` are not pythonic.

@arshajii metioned this solution:

```
len([x for x in n if x > 3])
```

This is quite simple, but is not describing what you exactly want to do, and it makes a list that may use some additional memory.
A better solution is using `sum` with generator:

```
sum(1 for x in n if x > 3)
```

(See more about generator here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#rationale)

However, `sum` with generator is actually slower in most cases because of the implementation (tested in CPython 3.6.4):

```
In [1]: %timeit len([1 for x in range(10000000)])
356 ms ± 17.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [2]: %timeit sum(1 for x in range(10000000))
676 ms ± 7.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 13):

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) for python 3 say it returns an iterator

> "Construct an iterator from those elements of iterable for which
>   function returns true."

In python 2 it returned a list: see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter). 
You will need to iterate the filter object to find its length.

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved using more-itertools:

```
from more_itertools import ilen
f = filter(lambda x:x>3,n)
return ilen(f)
```

Note that `ilen` consumes the filter (you won't be able to use it afterwards - it will return an empty list)