# Flask: 404 The requested URL was not found on the server.

Tags: python, curl, flask

I am trying to run the portion of the code with Curl and Flask. But I a getting the 404 error. I am pretty sure I am writing the code right as well. But it's giving me the error.

Code:

```
    @app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_task(task_id):
    task = [task for task in tasks if task['id'] == task_id]
    if len(task) == 0:
        abort(404)
    return jsonify({'task': task[0]})
```

REQEST: curl -i http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/2

Comment: How and where do you run `app`?

Comment: I fixed the issue. I placed the app. run before the @app.route got to do it's thing! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to check where you app.run is. It needs to be in the bottom of the file.

```
...
if __name__ = '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 it's can fix like this for example:

```
list(filter(lambda t: t['id'] == task_id, tasks))
```

[How to find the length of a "filter" object in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182188/how-to-find-the-length-of-a-filter-object-in-python)