# Fastest way to count non spacing chars in Unicode text in Python

Tags: python, unicode

Given the Unicode non spacing marks list - https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm

```
UNICODE_NSM = ['\u0300', '\u0301', '\u0302', '\u0303', '\u0304', '\u0305', '\u0306', '\u0307', '\u0308', '\u0309', '\u030A', '\u030B', '\u030C', '\u030D', '\u030E', '\u030F', '\u0310', '\u0311', '\u0312', '\u0313', '\u0314', '\u0315', '\u0316', '\u0317', '\u0318', '\u0319', '\u031A', '\u031B', '\u031C', '\u031D', '\u031E', '\u031F', '\u0320', '\u0321', '\u0322', '\u0323', '\u0324', '\u0325', '\u0326', '\u0327', '\u0328', '\u0329', '\u032A', '\u032B', '\u032C', '\u032D', '\u032E', '\u032F', '\u0330', '\u0331', '\u0332', '\u0333', '\u0334', '\u0335', '\u0336', '\u0337', '\u0338', '\u0339', '\u033A', '\u033B', '\u033C', '\u033D', '\u033E', '\u033F', '\u0340', '\u0341', '\u0342', '\u0343', '\u0344', '\u0345', '\u0346', '\u0347', '\u0348', '\u0349', '\u034A', '\u034B', '\u034C', '\u034D', '\u034E', '\u034F', '\u0350', '\u0351', '\u0352', '\u0353', '\u0354', '\u0355', '\u0356', '\u0357', '\u0358', '\u0359', '\u035A', '\u035B', '\u035C', '\u035D', '\u035E', '\u035F', '\u0360', '\u0361', '\u0362', '\u0363', '\u0364', '\u0365', '\u0366', '\u0367', '\u0368', '\u0369', '\u036A', '\u036B', '\u036C', '\u036D', '\u036E', '\u036F', '\u0483', '\u0484', '\u0485', '\u0486', '\u0487', '\u0591', '\u0592', '\u0593', '\u0594', '\u0595', '\u0596', '\u0597', '\u0598', '\u0599', '\u059A', '\u059B', '\u059C', '\u059D', '\u059E', '\u059F', '\u05A0', '\u05A1', '\u05A2', '\u05A3', '\u05A4', '\u05A5', '\u05A6', '\u05A7', '\u05A8', '\u05A9', '\u05AA', '\u05AB', '\u05AC', '\u05AD', '\u05AE', '\u05AF', '\u05B0', '\u05B1', '\u05B2', '\u05B3', '\u05B4', '\u05B5', '\u05B6', '\u05B7', '\u05B8', '\u05B9', '\u05BA', '\u05BB', '\u05BC', '\u05BD', '\u05BF', '\u05C1', '\u05C2', '\u05C4', '\u05C5', '\u05C7', '\u0610', '\u0611', '\u0612', '\u0613', '\u0614', '\u0615', '\u0616', '\u0617', '\u0618', '\u0619', '\u061A', '\u064B', '\u064C', '\u064D', '\u064E', '\u064F', '\u0650', '\u0651', '\u0652', '\u0653', '\u0654', '\u0655', '\u0656', '\u0657', '\u0658', '\u0659', '\u065A', '\u065B', '\u065C', '\u065D', '\u065E', '\u065F', '\u0670', '\u06D6', '\u06D7', '\u06D8', '\u06D9', '\u06DA', '\u06DB', '\u06DC', '\u06DF', '\u06E0', '\u06E1', '\u06E2', '\u06E3', '\u06E4', '\u06E7', '\u06E8', '\u06EA', '\u06EB', '\u06EC', '\u06ED', '\u0711', '\u0730', '\u0731', '\u0732', '\u0733', '\u0734', '\u0735', '\u0736', '\u0737', '\u0738', '\u0739', '\u073A', '\u073B', '\u073C', '\u073D', '\u073E', '\u073F', '\u0740', '\u0741', '\u0742', '\u0743', '\u0744', '\u0745', '\u0746', '\u0747', '\u0748', '\u0749', '\u074A', '\u07A6', '\u07A7', '\u07A8', '\u07A9', '\u07AA', '\u07AB', '\u07AC', '\u07AD', '\u07AE', '\u07AF', '\u07B0', '\u07EB', '\u07EC', '\u07ED', '\u07EE', '\u07EF', '\u07F0', '\u07F1', '\u07F2', '\u07F3', '\u0816', '\u0817', '\u0818', '\u0819', '\u081B', '\u081C', '\u081D', '\u081E', '\u081F', '\u0820', '\u0821', '\u0822', '\u0823', '\u0825', '\u0826', '\u0827', '\u0829', '\u082A', '\u082B', '\u082C', '\u082D', '\u0859', '\u085A', '\u085B', '\u08E4', '\u08E5', '\u08E6', '\u08E7', '\u08E8', '\u08E9', '\u08EA', '\u08EB', '\u08EC', '\u08ED', '\u08EE', '\u08EF', '\u08F0', '\u08F1', '\u08F2', '\u08F3', '\u08F4', '\u08F5', '\u08F6', '\u08F7', '\u08F8', '\u08F9', '\u08FA', '\u08FB', '\u08FC', '\u08FD', '\u08FE', '\u0900', '\u0901', '\u0902', '\u093A', '\u093C', '\u093E', '\u0941', '\u0942', '\u0943', '\u0944', '\u0945', '\u0946', '\u0947', '\u0948', '\u094D', '\u0951', '\u0952', '\u0953', '\u0954', '\u0955', '\u0956', '\u0957', '\u0962', '\u0963', '\u0981', '\u09BC', '\u09C1', '\u09C2', '\u09C3', '\u09C4', '\u09CD', '\u09E2', '\u09E3', '\u0A01', '\u0A02', '\u0A3C', '\u0A41', '\u0A42', '\u0A47', '\u0A48', '\u0A4B', '\u0A4C', '\u0A4D', '\u0A51', '\u0A70', '\u0A71', '\u0A75', '\u0A81', '\u0A82', '\u0ABC', '\u0AC1', '\u0AC2', '\u0AC3', '\u0AC4', '\u0AC5', '\u0AC7', '\u0AC8', '\u0ACD', '\u0AE2', '\u0AE3', '\u0B01', '\u0B3C', '\u0B3F', '\u0B41', '\u0B42', '\u0B43', '\u0B44', '\u0B4D', '\u0B56', '\u0B62', '\u0B63', '\u0B82', '\u0BC0', '\u0BCD', '\u0C3E', '\u0C3F', '\u0C40', '\u0C46', '\u0C47', '\u0C48', '\u0C4A', '\u0C4B', '\u0C4C', '\u0C4D', '\u0C55', '\u0C56', '\u0C62', '\u0C63', '\u0CBC', '\u0CBF', '\u0CC6', '\u0CCC', '\u0CCD', '\u0CE2', '\u0CE3', '\u0D41', '\u0D42', '\u0D43', '\u0D44', '\u0D4D', '\u0D62', '\u0D63', '\u0DCA', '\u0DD2', '\u0DD3', '\u0DD4', '\u0DD6', '\u0E31', '\u0E34', '\u0E35', '\u0E36', '\u0E37', '\u0E38', '\u0E39', '\u0E3A', '\u0E47', '\u0E48', '\u0E49', '\u0E4A', '\u0E4B', '\u0E4C', '\u0E4D', '\u0E4E', '\u0EB1', '\u0EB4', '\u0EB5', '\u0EB6', '\u0EB7', '\u0EB8', '\u0EB9', '\u0EBB', '\u0EBC', '\u0EC8', '\u0EC9', '\u0ECA', '\u0ECB', '\u0ECC', '\u0ECD', '\u0F18', '\u0F19', '\u0F35', '\u0F37', '\u0F39', '\u0F71', '\u0F72', '\u0F73', '\u0F74', '\u0F75', '\u0F76', '\u0F77', '\u0F78', '\u0F79', '\u0F7A', '\u0F7B', '\u0F7C', '\u0F7D', '\u0F7E', '\u0F80', '\u0F81', '\u0F82', '\u0F83', '\u0F84', '\u0F86', '\u0F87', '\u0F8D', '\u0F8E', '\u0F8F', '\u0F90', '\u0F91', '\u0F92', '\u0F93', '\u0F94', '\u0F95', '\u0F96', '\u0F97', '\u0F99', '\u0F9A', '\u0F9B', '\u0F9C', '\u0F9D', '\u0F9E', '\u0F9F', '\u0FA0', '\u0FA1', '\u0FA2', '\u0FA3', '\u0FA4', '\u0FA5', '\u0FA6', '\u0FA7', '\u0FA8', '\u0FA9', '\u0FAA', '\u0FAB', '\u0FAC', '\u0FAD', '\u0FAE', '\u0FAF', '\u0FB0', '\u0FB1', '\u0FB2', '\u0FB3', '\u0FB4', '\u0FB5', '\u0FB6', '\u0FB7', '\u0FB8', '\u0FB9', '\u0FBA', '\u0FBB', '\u0FBC', '\u0FC6', '\u102D', '\u102E', '\u102F', '\u1030', '\u1032', '\u1033', '\u1034', '\u1035', '\u1036', '\u1037', '\u1039', '\u103A', '\u103D', '\u103E', '\u1058', '\u1059', '\u105E', '\u105F', '\u1060', '\u1071', '\u1072', '\u1073', '\u1074', '\u1082', '\u1085', '\u1086', '\u108D', '\u109D', '\u135D', '\u135E', '\u135F', '\u1712', '\u1713', '\u1714', '\u1732', '\u1733', '\u1734', '\u1752', '\u1753', '\u1772', '\u1773', '\u17B4', '\u17B5', '\u17B7', '\u17B8', '\u17B9', '\u17BA', '\u17BB', '\u17BC', '\u17BD', '\u17C6', '\u17C9', '\u17CA', '\u17CB', '\u17CC', '\u17CD', '\u17CE', '\u17CF', '\u17D0', '\u17D1', '\u17D2', '\u17D3', '\u17DD', '\u180B', '\u180C', '\u180D', '\u18A9', '\u1920', '\u1921', '\u1922', '\u1927', '\u1928', '\u1932', '\u1939', '\u193A', '\u193B', '\u1A17', '\u1A18', '\u1A56', '\u1A58', '\u1A59', '\u1A5A', '\u1A5B', '\u1A5C', '\u1A5D', '\u1A5E', '\u1A60', '\u1A62', '\u1A65', '\u1A66', '\u1A67', '\u1A68', '\u1A69', '\u1A6A', '\u1A6B', '\u1A6C', '\u1A73', '\u1A74', '\u1A75', '\u1A76', '\u1A77', '\u1A78', '\u1A79', '\u1A7A', '\u1A7B', '\u1A7C', '\u1A7F', '\u1B00', '\u1B01', '\u1B02', '\u1B03', '\u1B34', '\u1B36', '\u1B37', '\u1B38', '\u1B39', '\u1B3A', '\u1B3C', '\u1B42', '\u1B6B', '\u1B6C', '\u1B6D', '\u1B6E', '\u1B6F', '\u1B70', '\u1B71', '\u1B72', '\u1B73', '\u1B80', '\u1B81', '\u1BA2', '\u1BA3', '\u1BA4', '\u1BA5', '\u1BA8', '\u1BA9', '\u1BAB', '\u1BE6', '\u1BE8', '\u1BE9', '\u1BED', '\u1BEF', '\u1BF0', '\u1BF1', '\u1C2C', '\u1C2D', '\u1C2E', '\u1C2F', '\u1C30', '\u1C31', '\u1C32', '\u1C33', '\u1C36', '\u1C37', '\u1CD0', '\u1CD1', '\u1CD2', '\u1CD4', '\u1CD5', '\u1CD6', '\u1CD7', '\u1CD8', '\u1CD9', '\u1CDA', '\u1CDB', '\u1CDC', '\u1CDD', '\u1CDE', '\u1CDF', '\u1CE0', '\u1CE2', '\u1CE3', '\u1CE4', '\u1CE5', '\u1CE6', '\u1CE7', '\u1CE8', '\u1CED', '\u1CF4', '\u1DC0', '\u1DC1', '\u1DC2', '\u1DC3', '\u1DC4', '\u1DC5', '\u1DC6', '\u1DC7', '\u1DC8', '\u1DC9', '\u1DCA', '\u1DCB', '\u1DCC', '\u1DCD', '\u1DCE', '\u1DCF', '\u1DD0', '\u1DD1', '\u1DD2', '\u1DD3', '\u1DD4', '\u1DD5', '\u1DD6', '\u1DD7', '\u1DD8', '\u1DD9', '\u1DDA', '\u1DDB', '\u1DDC', '\u1DDD', '\u1DDE', '\u1DDF', '\u1DE0', '\u1DE1', '\u1DE2', '\u1DE3', '\u1DE4', '\u1DE5', '\u1DE6', '\u1DFC', '\u1DFD', '\u1DFE', '\u1DFF', '\u20D0', '\u20D1', '\u20D2', '\u20D3', '\u20D4', '\u20D5', '\u20D6', '\u20D7', '\u20D8', '\u20D9', '\u20DA', '\u20DB', '\u20DC', '\u20E1', '\u20E5', '\u20E6', '\u20E7', '\u20E8', '\u20E9', '\u20EA', '\u20EB', '\u20EC', '\u20ED', '\u20EE', '\u20EF', '\u20F0', '\u2CEF', '\u2CF0', '\u2CF1', '\u2D7F', '\u2DE0', '\u2DE1', '\u2DE2', '\u2DE3', '\u2DE4', '\u2DE5', '\u2DE6', '\u2DE7', '\u2DE8', '\u2DE9', '\u2DEA', '\u2DEB', '\u2DEC', '\u2DED', '\u2DEE', '\u2DEF', '\u2DF0', '\u2DF1', '\u2DF2', '\u2DF3', '\u2DF4', '\u2DF5', '\u2DF6', '\u2DF7', '\u2DF8', '\u2DF9', '\u2DFA', '\u2DFB', '\u2DFC', '\u2DFD', '\u2DFE', '\u2DFF', '\u302A', '\u302B', '\u302C', '\u302D', '\u3099', '\u309A', '\uA66F', '\uA674', '\uA675', '\uA676', '\uA677', '\uA678', '\uA679', '\uA67A', '\uA67B', '\uA67C', '\uA67D', '\uA69F', '\uA6F0', '\uA6F1', '\uA802', '\uA806', '\uA80B', '\uA825', '\uA826', '\uA8C4', '\uA8E0', '\uA8E1', '\uA8E2', '\uA8E3', '\uA8E4', '\uA8E5', '\uA8E6', '\uA8E7', '\uA8E8', '\uA8E9', '\uA8EA', '\uA8EB', '\uA8EC', '\uA8ED', '\uA8EE', '\uA8EF', '\uA8F0', '\uA8F1', '\uA926', '\uA927', '\uA928', '\uA929', '\uA92A', '\uA92B', '\uA92C', '\uA92D', '\uA947', '\uA948', '\uA949', '\uA94A', '\uA94B', '\uA94C', '\uA94D', '\uA94E', '\uA94F', '\uA950', '\uA951', '\uA980', '\uA981', '\uA982', '\uA9B3', '\uA9B6', '\uA9B7', '\uA9B8', '\uA9B9', '\uA9BC', '\uAA29', '\uAA2A', '\uAA2B', '\uAA2C', '\uAA2D', '\uAA2E', '\uAA31', '\uAA32', '\uAA35', '\uAA36', '\uAA43', '\uAA4C', '\uAAB0', '\uAAB2', '\uAAB3', '\uAAB4', '\uAAB7', '\uAAB8', '\uAABE', '\uAABF', '\uAAC1', '\uAAEC', '\uAAED', '\uAAF6', '\uABE5', '\uABE8', '\uABED', '\uFB1E', '\uFE00', '\uFE01', '\uFE02', '\uFE03', '\uFE04', '\uFE05', '\uFE06', '\uFE07', '\uFE08', '\uFE09', '\uFE0A', '\uFE0B', '\uFE0C', '\uFE0D', '\uFE0E', '\uFE0F', '\uFE20', '\uFE21', '\uFE22', '\uFE23', '\uFE24', '\uFE25', '\uFE26', '\U000101FD', '\U00010A01', '\U00010A02', '\U00010A03', '\U00010A05', '\U00010A06', '\U00010A0C', '\U00010A0D', '\U00010A0E', '\U00010A0F', '\U00010A38', '\U00010A39', '\U00010A3A', '\U00010A3F', '\U00011001', '\U00011038', '\U00011039', '\U0001103A', '\U0001103B', '\U0001103C', '\U0001103D', '\U0001103E', '\U0001103F', '\U00011040', '\U00011041', '\U00011042', '\U00011043', '\U00011044', '\U00011045', '\U00011046', '\U00011080', '\U00011081', '\U000110B3', '\U000110B4', '\U000110B5', '\U000110B6', '\U000110B9', '\U000110BA', '\U00011100', '\U00011101', '\U00011102', '\U00011127', '\U00011128', '\U00011129', '\U0001112A', '\U0001112B', '\U0001112D', '\U0001112E', '\U0001112F', '\U00011130', '\U00011131', '\U00011132', '\U00011133', '\U00011134', '\U00011180', '\U00011181', '\U000111B6', '\U000111B7', '\U000111B8', '\U000111B9', '\U000111BA', '\U000111BB', '\U000111BC', '\U000111BD', '\U000111BE', '\U000116AB', '\U000116AD', '\U000116B0', '\U000116B1', '\U000116B2', '\U000116B3', '\U000116B4', '\U000116B5', '\U000116B7', '\U00016F8F', '\U00016F90', '\U00016F91', '\U00016F92', '\U0001D167', '\U0001D168', '\U0001D169', '\U0001D17B', '\U0001D17C', '\U0001D17D', '\U0001D17E', '\U0001D17F', '\U0001D180', '\U0001D181', '\U0001D182', '\U0001D185', '\U0001D186', '\U0001D187', '\U0001D188', '\U0001D189', '\U0001D18A', '\U0001D18B', '\U0001D1AA', '\U0001D1AB', '\U0001D1AC', '\U0001D1AD', '\U0001D242', '\U0001D243', '\U0001D244', '\U000E0100', '\U000E0101', '\U000E0102', '\U000E0103', '\U000E0104', '\U000E0105', '\U000E0106', '\U000E0107', '\U000E0108', '\U000E0109', '\U000E010A', '\U000E010B', '\U000E010C', '\U000E010D', '\U000E010E', '\U000E010F', '\U000E0110', '\U000E0111', '\U000E0112', '\U000E0113', '\U000E0114', '\U000E0115', '\U000E0116', '\U000E0117', '\U000E0118', '\U000E0119', '\U000E011A', '\U000E011B', '\U000E011C', '\U000E011D', '\U000E011E', '\U000E011F', '\U000E0120', '\U000E0121', '\U000E0122', '\U000E0123', '\U000E0124', '\U000E0125', '\U000E0126', '\U000E0127', '\U000E0128', '\U000E0129', '\U000E012A', '\U000E012B', '\uE012C', '\U000E012D', '\U000E012E', '\U000E012F', '\U000E0130', '\U000E0131', '\U000E0132', '\U000E0133', '\U000E0134', '\U000E0135', '\U000E0136', '\U000E0137', '\U000E0138', '\U000E0139', '\U000E013A', '\U000E013B', '\U000E013C', '\U000E013D', '\U000E013E', '\U000E013F', '\U000E0140', '\U000E0141', '\U000E0142', '\U000E0143', '\U000E0144', '\U000E0145', '\U000E0146', '\U000E0147', '\U000E0148', '\U000E0149', '\U000E014A', '\U000E014B', '\U000E014C', '\U000E014D', '\U000E014E', '\U000E014F', '\U000E0150', '\U000E0151', '\U000E0152', '\U000E0153', '\U000E0154', '\U000E0155', '\U000E0156', '\U000E0157', '\U000E0158', '\U000E0159', '\U000E015A', '\U000E015B', '\U000E015C', '\U000E015D', '\U000E015E', '\U000E015F', '\U000E0160', '\U000E0161', '\U000E0162', '\U000E0163', '\U000E0164', '\U000E0165', '\U000E0166', '\U000E0167', '\U000E0168', '\U000E0169', '\U000E016A', '\U000E016B', '\U000E016C', '\U000E016D', '\U000E016E', '\U000E016F', '\U000E0170', '\U000E0171', '\U000E0172', '\U000E0173', '\U000E0174', '\U000E0175', '\U000E0176', '\U000E0177', '\U000E0178', '\U000E0179', '\U000E017A', '\U000E017B', '\U000E017C', '\U000E017D', '\U000E017E', '\U000E017F', '\U000E0180', '\U000E0181', '\U000E0182', '\U000E0183', '\U000E0184', '\U000E0185', '\uE0186', '\U000E0187', '\U000E0188', '\U000E0189', '\U000E018A', '\U000E018B', '\U000E018C', '\U000E018D', '\U000E018E', '\U000E018F', '\U000E0190', '\U000E0191', '\U000E0192', '\U000E0193', '\U000E0194', '\U000E0195', '\U000E0196', '\U000E0197', '\U000E0198', '\U000E0199', '\U000E019A', '\U000E019B', '\U000E019C', '\U000E019D', '\U000E019E', '\U000E019F', '\U000E01A0', '\U000E01A1', '\U000E01A2', '\U000E01A3', '\U000E01A4', '\U000E01A5', '\U000E01A6', '\U000E01A7', '\U000E01A8', '\U000E01A9', '\U000E01AA', '\U000E01AB', '\U000E01AC', '\U000E01AD', '\U000E01AE', '\U000E01AF', '\U000E01B0', '\U000E01B1', '\U000E01B2', '\U000E01B3', '\U000E01B4', '\U000E01B5', '\U000E01B6', '\U000E01B7', '\U000E01B8', '\U000E01B9', '\U000E01BA', '\U000E01BB', '\U000E01BC', '\U000E01BD', '\U000E01BE', '\U000E01BF', '\U000E01C0', '\U000E01C1', '\U000E01C2', '\U000E01C3', '\U000E01C4', '\U000E01C5', '\U000E01C6', '\U000E01C7', '\U000E01C8', '\U000E01C9', '\U000E01CA', '\U000E01CB', '\U000E01CC', '\U000E01CD', '\U000E01CE', '\U000E01CF', '\U000E01D0', '\U000E01D1', '\U000E01D2', '\U000E01D3', '\U000E01D4', '\U000E01D5', '\U000E01D6', '\U000E01D7', '\U000E01D8', '\U000E01D9', '\U000E01DA', '\U000E01DB', '\U000E01DC', '\U000E01DD', '\U000E01DE', '\U000E01DF', '\U000E01E0', '\U000E01E1', '\U000E01E2', '\U000E01E3', '\U000E01E4', '\U000E01E5', '\U000E01E6', '\U000E01E7', '\U000E01E8', '\U000E01E9', '\U000E01EA', '\U000E01EB', '\U000E01EC', '\U000E01ED', '\U000E01EE', '\U000E01EF'];
```

**NOTE.**
Please note that we have both `\U000XXXXX` and `\uXXXX` representations here.

I want to count the Unicode input text like this Hindi string "अब यहां से कहा जाएँ हम" or just a token word like "समझा", excluding the non spacing characters.

My implementation looks like

```
def countNonSpacingCharString(str):
  count = 0;
  for char in str:
    if char not in UNICODE_NSM:
      count = count + 1
  return count
```

Thanks to the help provided in the answers below I have put all together in this github. There is also a mark codepoints list ready to be used in JavaScript / Node.js - https://github.com/loretoparisi/unicode_marks

Comment: What would be a spacing character? In regex there is `'\s'`, that represents the class of spaces, is that good enough? You also have `'\S'` that represents all characters not included in `'\s'`. Also you could check for spacing characters, I believe is a smaller set than all non-spacing.

Comment: What do you mean by "non spacing chars"? These all appear to be combining marks. That is, unicode points that are not valid characters on their own, but modify other valid unicode characters. eg. `u'o\u0300'` is the decomposed form of [LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH GRAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%92).

Comment: Sorry i mean characters in the non spacing marks - https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm

Comment: Have you explored using numpy for this?

Comment: I've noticed your encoding of unicode points greater than `'\uffff'` is wrong. eg. `'\ue01eF'`is interpreted as `'\ue01e' + 'F'`. The correct representation for these longer unicode points is `'\UXXXXXXXX'` (note the capital U) eg. `'\U000e01ef'`.

Comment: @Dunes doh that's correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what your end goal, but you talk of not counting "non spacing marks", but your list of characters also include "spacing marks" (such as `'\u093E'`  or DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN AA). And yet it is also missing other spacing marks such as `'\u0940'` or DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN II, which is found in your third sample at index 24. There are possibly other missing or erroneously included characters, including in the NSM category. So you'll need to triple check to make your character set is correct for your use case.

Comment: gosh! So I aim to correctly find the `length` and the `offset` of a text like the hindi text `"अब यहां से कहा जाएँ हम"`. In cases like this, using `.length` will give you the wrong size.

Comment: Right, both those types (spacing and non spacing marks) modify a glyph, but that glyph is still only counted as one character by a human. A non spacing mark doesn't changed the width of the glyph, but a spacing mark does (imagine a Unicode point that could turn a `v` into a `w`). So given your third sample, what do you think it's length should be? My browser shows there are 15 distinct selectable glyphs of which 4 are spaces. I'm under the impression that you would think the length should be 15 then? Whereas `len(s)` gives 22 and your current implementation gives 16.

Comment: Got that last bit wrong as I accidentally pasted the quotes into the string. There are 11 distinct Devanagari glyphs and 5 spaces, for a total of 16 characters. That's the answer you're looking for then?

Comment: @Dunes yes because while `"अब यहां से कहा जाएँ हम".length` gives 22, the visible size it is 16 i.e. if you put the cursor at the end, and you count each space when you press the right arrow, it's 16. So if I use the `countNonSpacingCharString` this gives me that size. Is it correct?

Comment: This is getting a bit beyond my knowledge of Unicode, I have to admit. I'll post a new answer, which should hopefully help though.

Comment: Thank you! I would also remove the "This solution performances are" part - including time-code in your snippet. It is just confusing. Performance should be measured as a whole, not for a single operation. And with timeit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fastest way I came up with.  `len` was slightly faster than `sum`.  I built a set of all combining mark types in the setup.

**test.py:**

```
import sys
from unicodedata import category

MARK_SET = set(chr(c) for c in range(sys.maxunicode + 1) if category(chr(c))[0] == 'M')

s = "अब यहां से कहा जाएँ हम"

def count_len(s):
    return len([c for c in s if c not in MARK_SET])

def count_sum(s):
    return sum([c not in MARK_SET for c in s])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(len(s))
    print(count_len(s))
    print(count_sum(s))
```

**Output:**

```
22
16
16
```

**Timings:**

```
C:\>py -m timeit -s "from test import count_sum,s" "count_sum(s)"
50000 loops, best of 5: 4.62 usec per loop

C:\>py -m timeit -s "from test import count_len,s" "count_len(s)"
50000 loops, best of 5: 3.97 usec per loop
```

It's worth noting that there is a grapheme 3rd party library.  `grapheme.length(s) == 16`, but it was *much* slower (118us).  The full grapheme-detecting algorithm is more complicated than skipping the modifier category.  Consider the combining emojis for families and skin colors.

See also [Unicode Text Segmentation](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

Comment: Thanks! This works fine in Python 3.5. But when in Python2.7 I get this error: `TypeError: category() argument 1 must be unicode, not str`.

Comment: So, if I use `unichar` instead of `char` will fix it, but the number of mark symbols are fewer.

Comment: @loretoparisi Python 2 and 3 code is not compatible. Python 3 has better support for Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a better alternative:

```
def countNonSpacingCharString(str):
    return len([char for char in str if not(char in UNICODE_NSM)])
```

Comment: You could make it a generator and use sum

Comment: But please timeit, otherwise it is just guessing

Comment: Using a generator is a great suggestion, I timed my suggestion but there is no observable difference from what I see. However one cannot deduce that just by a couple of runs.

Comment: If you used [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), please post the results (for all approaches)

Comment: According to the test results, this is the faster approach in combinations with `SET` instead of `LIST`.

Answer (score 1):

I must note that using `str`, as variable name in Python is bad idea, as it is name of built-in function. Anyway I would implement your function following way:

```
def countNonSpacingCharString(s):
    return len(filter(lambda x:not x in UNICODE_NSM,s))
```

in Python 2

```
def countNonSpacingCharString(s):
    return sum(1 for _ in filter(lambda x:not x in UNICODE_NSM,s))
```

in Python 3

Inspecting my function using `dis.dis` showed that it produced less bytecode than your version with `count`, thus suggesting it *might* be faster, though this need further investigation.

EDIT: I tested my code in Python 2, but not Python 3 - version for Python 3 added, using Mohammad Banisaeid answer from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182188/how-to-find-the-length-of-a-filter-object-in-python).

EDIT 2: If you uses `UNICODE_NSM` only for that, you might try to use `set` instead of `list`, which should boost `in` operator, though again this need further investigation. For discussion about `list` vs `set` performance see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831212/python-sets-vs-lists/17945009).

Comment: This returns the following error: `TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()`

Comment: I edited and added further tests for each implementation.

Comment: I must admit my intuition of shorter (one-liner) code is faster somewhat failed, as your implemention looks to be on-par timewise with mine, anyway I am glad that `set` instead of `list` helped. Is now that function fast enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a dictionary to look up the values and if not present, increment the count? It should be faster than the former approach because the time complexity to check the presence of the character reduces to O(1).

The implementation should look somewhat like this:

1. Create a dict and populate it:

   `lookup_dict = {}
   for alpha in UNICODE_NSM:
     lookup_dict[alpha] = 1`
2. Look it up while looping through the string:

   `def countNonSpacingCharString(str):
     count = 0;
     for char in str:
       start_time = time.time()
       if not lookup_dict.get(char):
         count = count + 1
       print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
     return count`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this is to use the [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) module. In part, because it will be more rigorously tested. Indeed, I found your list appeared to be including categories other than `Mn`. That is, it includes Unicode points from `Mc` (Mark, spacing combining) as well, but you said you only wanted to exclude Unicode points from `Mn` (Mark, Nonspacing).

eg.

```
import unicodedata 

def countNonSpacingCharString(string):
    category = unicodedata.category
    return sum(category(char) != 'Mn' for char in string)
```

This appears to be about 60 times faster according to `timeit`.

You might get a `TypeError`, if your version of Python and therefore `unicodedata` is not up-to-date, and so not aware of recent additions to Unicode. You can get around this by installing `unicodedata2` and using that instead.

Comment: That's interesting! Strangerly in repl.py I cannot import `unicodedata`. See here I'm adjusting all possibile tests - https://repl.it/@loretoparisi/NonSpacingUnicodeChars

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it looks like you're really after counting "user perceived characters". This is a complicated process with a number of edge cases. If you can then you should to install [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) on your environment (that would be micropython?). You can then do:

```
>>> parts = regex.findall(r'\X', 'अब यहां से कहा जाएँ हम')
>>> parts
['अ', 'ब', ' ', 'य', 'हां', ' ', 'से', ' ', 'क', 'हा', ' ', 'जा', 'एँ', ' ', 'ह', 'म']
>>> len(parts)
16
```

Which splits your string into "user perceived characters", and then you can work on this list of strings to get what you need.

Failing that, your current solution of just ignoring Mark code points is an 80/20 solution (gets you most of the way their for the least amount of effort). You will have to revise what your list of Unicode marks though. My tests showed that your list was missing 113 code points across all the Indo-European and Dravidian scripts in Unicode (Devanagari, Bengali, Gurmukhi, Gujarati, Oriya, Tamil, Telugu, Kannada, Malayalam, and Sinhala).

I extracted these characters by downloading and parsing: https://www.unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt with the following code:

```
indian_script_range = range(0x0900, 0x0E00) # doesn't include all indic scripts (eg. Thai)
basic_multilingual_plane = range(0x0000, 0x10000)  
# use the latter if you want to be more thorough and include all indic scripts and non-indic scripts
codepoint_range = indian_script_range

codepoints = []

with open('UnicodeData.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        hex_string, name, category, *rest = line.strip().split(';')
        codepoint_number = int(hex_string, base=16)
        if (
            category in ('Mn', 'Mc', 'Me')
            and (
                codepoint_number in codepoint_range
                or name.startswith('VARIATION SELECTOR') # you seemed to want to include these
            )
        ):
            codepoints.append(chr(codepoint_number))

missing = set(codepoints) - set(UNICODE_NSM)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have put all together here both in Python and JavaScript. There were a few issues in Python 2.7 to be handled - https://github.com/loretoparisi/unicode_marks

Answer (score 1):

[Mark Tolonens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358186/562769) is the fastest, because it uses a `set` for comparison. If you have a text of length `n` and `m` whitespace-characters to compare with, then your worst-case runtime using two lists is O(nm). Using a set for the whitespace characters reduces that to O(n).

Using `unicodedata.category` is just nicer because it is shorter and less prone to human error.

### Performance comparison

[image]

You can clearly see that the `markset_count` and the `category_count` are way faster than the `generator_count` and the `loop_count`. Also the speed of the latter two varies way more. Interestingly, the `generator_count` is slower than the `loop_count`.

The `markset_count` is a bit faster than the `category_count`. I think that is the case because looking up the category and doing the string comparison also takes a bit of time. The difference is way more clear when you only plot the two and increase the text length:

[image]

```
import timeit
import sys
import unicodedata
import numpy as np

UNICODE_NSM = ['\u0300', '\u0301', '\u0302', '\u0303', '\u0304', '\u0305', '\u0306', '\u0307', '\u0308', '\u0309', '\u030A', '\u030B', '\u030C', '\u030D', '\u030E', '\u030F', '\u0310', '\u0311', '\u0312', '\u0313', '\u0314', '\u0315', '\u0316', '\u0317', '\u0318', '\u0319', '\u031A', '\u031B', '\u031C', '\u031D', '\u031E', '\u031F', '\u0320', '\u0321', '\u0322', '\u0323', '\u0324', '\u0325', '\u0326', '\u0327', '\u0328', '\u0329', '\u032A', '\u032B', '\u032C', '\u032D', '\u032E', '\u032F', '\u0330', '\u0331', '\u0332', '\u0333', '\u0334', '\u0335', '\u0336', '\u0337', '\u0338', '\u0339', '\u033A', '\u033B', '\u033C', '\u033D', '\u033E', '\u033F', '\u0340', '\u0341', '\u0342', '\u0343', '\u0344', '\u0345', '\u0346', '\u0347', '\u0348', '\u0349', '\u034A', '\u034B', '\u034C', '\u034D', '\u034E', '\u034F', '\u0350', '\u0351', '\u0352', '\u0353', '\u0354', '\u0355', '\u0356', '\u0357', '\u0358', '\u0359', '\u035A', '\u035B', '\u035C', '\u035D', '\u035E', '\u035F', '\u0360', '\u0361', '\u0362', '\u0363', '\u0364', '\u0365', '\u0366', '\u0367', '\u0368', '\u0369', '\u036A', '\u036B', '\u036C', '\u036D', '\u036E', '\u036F', '\u0483', '\u0484', '\u0485', '\u0486', '\u0487', '\u0591', '\u0592', '\u0593', '\u0594', '\u0595', '\u0596', '\u0597', '\u0598', '\u0599', '\u059A', '\u059B', '\u059C', '\u059D', '\u059E', '\u059F', '\u05A0', '\u05A1', '\u05A2', '\u05A3', '\u05A4', '\u05A5', '\u05A6', '\u05A7', '\u05A8', '\u05A9', '\u05AA', '\u05AB', '\u05AC', '\u05AD', '\u05AE', '\u05AF', '\u05B0', '\u05B1', '\u05B2', '\u05B3', '\u05B4', '\u05B5', '\u05B6', '\u05B7', '\u05B8', '\u05B9', '\u05BA', '\u05BB', '\u05BC', '\u05BD', '\u05BF', '\u05C1', '\u05C2', '\u05C4', '\u05C5', '\u05C7', '\u0610', '\u0611', '\u0612', '\u0613', '\u0614', '\u0615', '\u0616', '\u0617', '\u0618', '\u0619', '\u061A', '\u064B', '\u064C', '\u064D', '\u064E', '\u064F', '\u0650', '\u0651', '\u0652', '\u0653', '\u0654', '\u0655', '\u0656', '\u0657', '\u0658', '\u0659', '\u065A', '\u065B', '\u065C', '\u065D', '\u065E', '\u065F', '\u0670', '\u06D6', '\u06D7', '\u06D8', '\u06D9', '\u06DA', '\u06DB', '\u06DC', '\u06DF', '\u06E0', '\u06E1', '\u06E2', '\u06E3', '\u06E4', '\u06E7', '\u06E8', '\u06EA', '\u06EB', '\u06EC', '\u06ED', '\u0711', '\u0730', '\u0731', '\u0732', '\u0733', '\u0734', '\u0735', '\u0736', '\u0737', '\u0738', '\u0739', '\u073A', '\u073B', '\u073C', '\u073D', '\u073E', '\u073F', '\u0740', '\u0741', '\u0742', '\u0743', '\u0744', '\u0745', '\u0746', '\u0747', '\u0748', '\u0749', '\u074A', '\u07A6', '\u07A7', '\u07A8', '\u07A9', '\u07AA', '\u07AB', '\u07AC', '\u07AD', '\u07AE', '\u07AF', '\u07B0', '\u07EB', '\u07EC', '\u07ED', '\u07EE', '\u07EF', '\u07F0', '\u07F1', '\u07F2', '\u07F3', '\u0816', '\u0817', '\u0818', '\u0819', '\u081B', '\u081C', '\u081D', '\u081E', '\u081F', '\u0820', '\u0821', '\u0822', '\u0823', '\u0825', '\u0826', '\u0827', '\u0829', '\u082A', '\u082B', '\u082C', '\u082D', '\u0859', '\u085A', '\u085B', '\u08E4', '\u08E5', '\u08E6', '\u08E7', '\u08E8', '\u08E9', '\u08EA', '\u08EB', '\u08EC', '\u08ED', '\u08EE', '\u08EF', '\u08F0', '\u08F1', '\u08F2', '\u08F3', '\u08F4', '\u08F5', '\u08F6', '\u08F7', '\u08F8', '\u08F9', '\u08FA', '\u08FB', '\u08FC', '\u08FD', '\u08FE', '\u0900', '\u0901', '\u0902', '\u093A', '\u093C', '\u093E', '\u0941', '\u0942', '\u0943', '\u0944', '\u0945', '\u0946', '\u0947', '\u0948', '\u094D', '\u0951', '\u0952', '\u0953', '\u0954', '\u0955', '\u0956', '\u0957', '\u0962', '\u0963', '\u0981', '\u09BC', '\u09C1', '\u09C2', '\u09C3', '\u09C4', '\u09CD', '\u09E2', '\u09E3', '\u0A01', '\u0A02', '\u0A3C', '\u0A41', '\u0A42', '\u0A47', '\u0A48', '\u0A4B', '\u0A4C', '\u0A4D', '\u0A51', '\u0A70', '\u0A71', '\u0A75', '\u0A81', '\u0A82', '\u0ABC', '\u0AC1', '\u0AC2', '\u0AC3', '\u0AC4', '\u0AC5', '\u0AC7', '\u0AC8', '\u0ACD', '\u0AE2', '\u0AE3', '\u0B01', '\u0B3C', '\u0B3F', '\u0B41', '\u0B42', '\u0B43', '\u0B44', '\u0B4D', '\u0B56', '\u0B62', '\u0B63', '\u0B82', '\u0BC0', '\u0BCD', '\u0C3E', '\u0C3F', '\u0C40', '\u0C46', '\u0C47', '\u0C48', '\u0C4A', '\u0C4B', '\u0C4C', '\u0C4D', '\u0C55', '\u0C56', '\u0C62', '\u0C63', '\u0CBC', '\u0CBF', '\u0CC6', '\u0CCC', '\u0CCD', '\u0CE2', '\u0CE3', '\u0D41', '\u0D42', '\u0D43', '\u0D44', '\u0D4D', '\u0D62', '\u0D63', '\u0DCA', '\u0DD2', '\u0DD3', '\u0DD4', '\u0DD6', '\u0E31', '\u0E34', '\u0E35', '\u0E36', '\u0E37', '\u0E38', '\u0E39', '\u0E3A', '\u0E47', '\u0E48', '\u0E49', '\u0E4A', '\u0E4B', '\u0E4C', '\u0E4D', '\u0E4E', '\u0EB1', '\u0EB4', '\u0EB5', '\u0EB6', '\u0EB7', '\u0EB8', '\u0EB9', '\u0EBB', '\u0EBC', '\u0EC8', '\u0EC9', '\u0ECA', '\u0ECB', '\u0ECC', '\u0ECD', '\u0F18', '\u0F19', '\u0F35', '\u0F37', '\u0F39', '\u0F71', '\u0F72', '\u0F73', '\u0F74', '\u0F75', '\u0F76', '\u0F77', '\u0F78', '\u0F79', '\u0F7A', '\u0F7B', '\u0F7C', '\u0F7D', '\u0F7E', '\u0F80', '\u0F81', '\u0F82', '\u0F83', '\u0F84', '\u0F86', '\u0F87', '\u0F8D', '\u0F8E', '\u0F8F', '\u0F90', '\u0F91', '\u0F92', '\u0F93', '\u0F94', '\u0F95', '\u0F96', '\u0F97', '\u0F99', '\u0F9A', '\u0F9B', '\u0F9C', '\u0F9D', '\u0F9E', '\u0F9F', '\u0FA0', '\u0FA1', '\u0FA2', '\u0FA3', '\u0FA4', '\u0FA5', '\u0FA6', '\u0FA7', '\u0FA8', '\u0FA9', '\u0FAA', '\u0FAB', '\u0FAC', '\u0FAD', '\u0FAE', '\u0FAF', '\u0FB0', '\u0FB1', '\u0FB2', '\u0FB3', '\u0FB4', '\u0FB5', '\u0FB6', '\u0FB7', '\u0FB8', '\u0FB9', '\u0FBA', '\u0FBB', '\u0FBC', '\u0FC6', '\u102D', '\u102E', '\u102F', '\u1030', '\u1032', '\u1033', '\u1034', '\u1035', '\u1036', '\u1037', '\u1039', '\u103A', '\u103D', '\u103E', '\u1058', '\u1059', '\u105E', '\u105F', '\u1060', '\u1071', '\u1072', '\u1073', '\u1074', '\u1082', '\u1085', '\u1086', '\u108D', '\u109D', '\u135D', '\u135E', '\u135F', '\u1712', '\u1713', '\u1714', '\u1732', '\u1733', '\u1734', '\u1752', '\u1753', '\u1772', '\u1773', '\u17B4', '\u17B5', '\u17B7', '\u17B8', '\u17B9', '\u17BA', '\u17BB', '\u17BC', '\u17BD', '\u17C6', '\u17C9', '\u17CA', '\u17CB', '\u17CC', '\u17CD', '\u17CE', '\u17CF', '\u17D0', '\u17D1', '\u17D2', '\u17D3', '\u17DD', '\u180B', '\u180C', '\u180D', '\u18A9', '\u1920', '\u1921', '\u1922', '\u1927', '\u1928', '\u1932', '\u1939', '\u193A', '\u193B', '\u1A17', '\u1A18', '\u1A56', '\u1A58', '\u1A59', '\u1A5A', '\u1A5B', '\u1A5C', '\u1A5D', '\u1A5E', '\u1A60', '\u1A62', '\u1A65', '\u1A66', '\u1A67', '\u1A68', '\u1A69', '\u1A6A', '\u1A6B', '\u1A6C', '\u1A73', '\u1A74', '\u1A75', '\u1A76', '\u1A77', '\u1A78', '\u1A79', '\u1A7A', '\u1A7B', '\u1A7C', '\u1A7F', '\u1B00', '\u1B01', '\u1B02', '\u1B03', '\u1B34', '\u1B36', '\u1B37', '\u1B38', '\u1B39', '\u1B3A', '\u1B3C', '\u1B42', '\u1B6B', '\u1B6C', '\u1B6D', '\u1B6E', '\u1B6F', '\u1B70', '\u1B71', '\u1B72', '\u1B73', '\u1B80', '\u1B81', '\u1BA2', '\u1BA3', '\u1BA4', '\u1BA5', '\u1BA8', '\u1BA9', '\u1BAB', '\u1BE6', '\u1BE8', '\u1BE9', '\u1BED', '\u1BEF', '\u1BF0', '\u1BF1', '\u1C2C', '\u1C2D', '\u1C2E', '\u1C2F', '\u1C30', '\u1C31', '\u1C32', '\u1C33', '\u1C36', '\u1C37', '\u1CD0', '\u1CD1', '\u1CD2', '\u1CD4', '\u1CD5', '\u1CD6', '\u1CD7', '\u1CD8', '\u1CD9', '\u1CDA', '\u1CDB', '\u1CDC', '\u1CDD', '\u1CDE', '\u1CDF', '\u1CE0', '\u1CE2', '\u1CE3', '\u1CE4', '\u1CE5', '\u1CE6', '\u1CE7', '\u1CE8', '\u1CED', '\u1CF4', '\u1DC0', '\u1DC1', '\u1DC2', '\u1DC3', '\u1DC4', '\u1DC5', '\u1DC6', '\u1DC7', '\u1DC8', '\u1DC9', '\u1DCA', '\u1DCB', '\u1DCC', '\u1DCD', '\u1DCE', '\u1DCF', '\u1DD0', '\u1DD1', '\u1DD2', '\u1DD3', '\u1DD4', '\u1DD5', '\u1DD6', '\u1DD7', '\u1DD8', '\u1DD9', '\u1DDA', '\u1DDB', '\u1DDC', '\u1DDD', '\u1DDE', '\u1DDF', '\u1DE0', '\u1DE1', '\u1DE2', '\u1DE3', '\u1DE4', '\u1DE5', '\u1DE6', '\u1DFC', '\u1DFD', '\u1DFE', '\u1DFF', '\u20D0', '\u20D1', '\u20D2', '\u20D3', '\u20D4', '\u20D5', '\u20D6', '\u20D7', '\u20D8', '\u20D9', '\u20DA', '\u20DB', '\u20DC', '\u20E1', '\u20E5', '\u20E6', '\u20E7', '\u20E8', '\u20E9', '\u20EA', '\u20EB', '\u20EC', '\u20ED', '\u20EE', '\u20EF', '\u20F0', '\u2CEF', '\u2CF0', '\u2CF1', '\u2D7F', '\u2DE0', '\u2DE1', '\u2DE2', '\u2DE3', '\u2DE4', '\u2DE5', '\u2DE6', '\u2DE7', '\u2DE8', '\u2DE9', '\u2DEA', '\u2DEB', '\u2DEC', '\u2DED', '\u2DEE', '\u2DEF', '\u2DF0', '\u2DF1', '\u2DF2', '\u2DF3', '\u2DF4', '\u2DF5', '\u2DF6', '\u2DF7', '\u2DF8', '\u2DF9', '\u2DFA', '\u2DFB', '\u2DFC', '\u2DFD', '\u2DFE', '\u2DFF', '\u302A', '\u302B', '\u302C', '\u302D', '\u3099', '\u309A', '\uA66F', '\uA674', '\uA675', '\uA676', '\uA677', '\uA678', '\uA679', '\uA67A', '\uA67B', '\uA67C', '\uA67D', '\uA69F', '\uA6F0', '\uA6F1', '\uA802', '\uA806', '\uA80B', '\uA825', '\uA826', '\uA8C4', '\uA8E0', '\uA8E1', '\uA8E2', '\uA8E3', '\uA8E4', '\uA8E5', '\uA8E6', '\uA8E7', '\uA8E8', '\uA8E9', '\uA8EA', '\uA8EB', '\uA8EC', '\uA8ED', '\uA8EE', '\uA8EF', '\uA8F0', '\uA8F1', '\uA926', '\uA927', '\uA928', '\uA929', '\uA92A', '\uA92B', '\uA92C', '\uA92D', '\uA947', '\uA948', '\uA949', '\uA94A', '\uA94B', '\uA94C', '\uA94D', '\uA94E', '\uA94F', '\uA950', '\uA951', '\uA980', '\uA981', '\uA982', '\uA9B3', '\uA9B6', '\uA9B7', '\uA9B8', '\uA9B9', '\uA9BC', '\uAA29', '\uAA2A', '\uAA2B', '\uAA2C', '\uAA2D', '\uAA2E', '\uAA31', '\uAA32', '\uAA35', '\uAA36', '\uAA43', '\uAA4C', '\uAAB0', '\uAAB2', '\uAAB3', '\uAAB4', '\uAAB7', '\uAAB8', '\uAABE', '\uAABF', '\uAAC1', '\uAAEC', '\uAAED', '\uAAF6', '\uABE5', '\uABE8', '\uABED', '\uFB1E', '\uFE00', '\uFE01', '\uFE02', '\uFE03', '\uFE04', '\uFE05', '\uFE06', '\uFE07', '\uFE08', '\uFE09', '\uFE0A', '\uFE0B', '\uFE0C', '\uFE0D', '\uFE0E', '\uFE0F', '\uFE20', '\uFE21', '\uFE22', '\uFE23', '\uFE24', '\uFE25', '\uFE26', '\U000101FD', '\U00010A01', '\U00010A02', '\U00010A03', '\U00010A05', '\U00010A06', '\U00010A0C', '\U00010A0D', '\U00010A0E', '\U00010A0F', '\U00010A38', '\U00010A39', '\U00010A3A', '\U00010A3F', '\U00011001', '\U00011038', '\U00011039', '\U0001103A', '\U0001103B', '\U0001103C', '\U0001103D', '\U0001103E', '\U0001103F', '\U00011040', '\U00011041', '\U00011042', '\U00011043', '\U00011044', '\U00011045', '\U00011046', '\U00011080', '\U00011081', '\U000110B3', '\U000110B4', '\U000110B5', '\U000110B6', '\U000110B9', '\U000110BA', '\U00011100', '\U00011101', '\U00011102', '\U00011127', '\U00011128', '\U00011129', '\U0001112A', '\U0001112B', '\U0001112D', '\U0001112E', '\U0001112F', '\U00011130', '\U00011131', '\U00011132', '\U00011133', '\U00011134', '\U00011180', '\U00011181', '\U000111B6', '\U000111B7', '\U000111B8', '\U000111B9', '\U000111BA', '\U000111BB', '\U000111BC', '\U000111BD', '\U000111BE', '\U000116AB', '\U000116AD', '\U000116B0', '\U000116B1', '\U000116B2', '\U000116B3', '\U000116B4', '\U000116B5', '\U000116B7', '\U00016F8F', '\U00016F90', '\U00016F91', '\U00016F92', '\U0001D167', '\U0001D168', '\U0001D169', '\U0001D17B', '\U0001D17C', '\U0001D17D', '\U0001D17E', '\U0001D17F', '\U0001D180', '\U0001D181', '\U0001D182', '\U0001D185', '\U0001D186', '\U0001D187', '\U0001D188', '\U0001D189', '\U0001D18A', '\U0001D18B', '\U0001D1AA', '\U0001D1AB', '\U0001D1AC', '\U0001D1AD', '\U0001D242', '\U0001D243', '\U0001D244', '\U000E0100', '\U000E0101', '\U000E0102', '\U000E0103', '\U000E0104', '\U000E0105', '\U000E0106', '\U000E0107', '\U000E0108', '\U000E0109', '\U000E010A', '\U000E010B', '\U000E010C', '\U000E010D', '\U000E010E', '\U000E010F', '\U000E0110', '\U000E0111', '\U000E0112', '\U000E0113', '\U000E0114', '\U000E0115', '\U000E0116', '\U000E0117', '\U000E0118', '\U000E0119', '\U000E011A', '\U000E011B', '\U000E011C', '\U000E011D', '\U000E011E', '\U000E011F', '\U000E0120', '\U000E0121', '\U000E0122', '\U000E0123', '\U000E0124', '\U000E0125', '\U000E0126', '\U000E0127', '\U000E0128', '\U000E0129', '\U000E012A', '\U000E012B', '\uE012C', '\U000E012D', '\U000E012E', '\U000E012F', '\U000E0130', '\U000E0131', '\U000E0132', '\U000E0133', '\U000E0134', '\U000E0135', '\U000E0136', '\U000E0137', '\U000E0138', '\U000E0139', '\U000E013A', '\U000E013B', '\U000E013C', '\U000E013D', '\U000E013E', '\U000E013F', '\U000E0140', '\U000E0141', '\U000E0142', '\U000E0143', '\U000E0144', '\U000E0145', '\U000E0146', '\U000E0147', '\U000E0148', '\U000E0149', '\U000E014A', '\U000E014B', '\U000E014C', '\U000E014D', '\U000E014E', '\U000E014F', '\U000E0150', '\U000E0151', '\U000E0152', '\U000E0153', '\U000E0154', '\U000E0155', '\U000E0156', '\U000E0157', '\U000E0158', '\U000E0159', '\U000E015A', '\U000E015B', '\U000E015C', '\U000E015D', '\U000E015E', '\U000E015F', '\U000E0160', '\U000E0161', '\U000E0162', '\U000E0163', '\U000E0164', '\U000E0165', '\U000E0166', '\U000E0167', '\U000E0168', '\U000E0169', '\U000E016A', '\U000E016B', '\U000E016C', '\U000E016D', '\U000E016E', '\U000E016F', '\U000E0170', '\U000E0171', '\U000E0172', '\U000E0173', '\U000E0174', '\U000E0175', '\U000E0176', '\U000E0177', '\U000E0178', '\U000E0179', '\U000E017A', '\U000E017B', '\U000E017C', '\U000E017D', '\U000E017E', '\U000E017F', '\U000E0180', '\U000E0181', '\U000E0182', '\U000E0183', '\U000E0184', '\U000E0185', '\uE0186', '\U000E0187', '\U000E0188', '\U000E0189', '\U000E018A', '\U000E018B', '\U000E018C', '\U000E018D', '\U000E018E', '\U000E018F', '\U000E0190', '\U000E0191', '\U000E0192', '\U000E0193', '\U000E0194', '\U000E0195', '\U000E0196', '\U000E0197', '\U000E0198', '\U000E0199', '\U000E019A', '\U000E019B', '\U000E019C', '\U000E019D', '\U000E019E', '\U000E019F', '\U000E01A0', '\U000E01A1', '\U000E01A2', '\U000E01A3', '\U000E01A4', '\U000E01A5', '\U000E01A6', '\U000E01A7', '\U000E01A8', '\U000E01A9', '\U000E01AA', '\U000E01AB', '\U000E01AC', '\U000E01AD', '\U000E01AE', '\U000E01AF', '\U000E01B0', '\U000E01B1', '\U000E01B2', '\U000E01B3', '\U000E01B4', '\U000E01B5', '\U000E01B6', '\U000E01B7', '\U000E01B8', '\U000E01B9', '\U000E01BA', '\U000E01BB', '\U000E01BC', '\U000E01BD', '\U000E01BE', '\U000E01BF', '\U000E01C0', '\U000E01C1', '\U000E01C2', '\U000E01C3', '\U000E01C4', '\U000E01C5', '\U000E01C6', '\U000E01C7', '\U000E01C8', '\U000E01C9', '\U000E01CA', '\U000E01CB', '\U000E01CC', '\U000E01CD', '\U000E01CE', '\U000E01CF', '\U000E01D0', '\U000E01D1', '\U000E01D2', '\U000E01D3', '\U000E01D4', '\U000E01D5', '\U000E01D6', '\U000E01D7', '\U000E01D8', '\U000E01D9', '\U000E01DA', '\U000E01DB', '\U000E01DC', '\U000E01DD', '\U000E01DE', '\U000E01DF', '\U000E01E0', '\U000E01E1', '\U000E01E2', '\U000E01E3', '\U000E01E4', '\U000E01E5', '\U000E01E6', '\U000E01E7', '\U000E01E8', '\U000E01E9', '\U000E01EA', '\U000E01EB', '\U000E01EC', '\U000E01ED', '\U000E01EE', '\U000E01EF']
MARK_SET = set(chr(c) for c in range(sys.maxunicode + 1) if unicodedata.category(chr(c))[0] == 'M')
print('len(UNICODE_NSM) = {}'.format(len(UNICODE_NSM)))
print('len(MARK_SET) = {}'.format(len(MARK_SET)))

filepath = "UnicodeData.txt"
with open(filepath) as f:
    text = f.read()

text = text[:1000]


def main():
    ground_truth = loop_count(text)
    functions = [(loop_count, 'loop_count'),
                 (generator_count, 'generator_count'),
                 (category_count, 'category_count'),
                 (markset_count, 'markset_count'),
                 ]
    functions = functions[::-1]
    duration_list = {}
    for func, name in functions:
        is_correct = func(text) == ground_truth
        durations = timeit.repeat(lambda: func(text), repeat=500, number=3)
        if is_correct:
            correctness = 'correct'
        else:
            correctness = 'NOT correct'
        duration_list[name] = durations
        print('{func:<20}: {correctness}, '
              'min: {min:0.3f}s, mean: {mean:0.3f}s, max: {max:0.3f}s'
              .format(func=name,
                      correctness=correctness,
                      min=min(durations),
                      mean=np.mean(durations),
                      max=max(durations),
                      ))
        create_boxplot(duration_list)


def create_boxplot(duration_list):
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import operator
    plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 4), dpi=300,
               facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    sns.set(style="whitegrid")
    sorted_keys, sorted_vals = zip(*sorted(duration_list.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
    flierprops = dict(markerfacecolor='0.75', markersize=1,
                      linestyle='none')
    ax = sns.boxplot(data=sorted_vals, width=.3, orient='h',
                     flierprops=flierprops,)
    ax.set(xlabel="Time in s", ylabel="")
    plt.yticks(plt.yticks()[0], sorted_keys)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("output.png")


def generator_count(text):
    return sum(1 for char in text if char not in UNICODE_NSM)


def loop_count(text):
    # 1769137
    count = 0
    for char in text:
        if char not in UNICODE_NSM:
            count += 1
    return count


def markset_count(text):
    return sum(char not in MARK_SET for char in text)


def category_count(text):
    return sum(unicodedata.category(char) != 'Mn' for char in text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed analysis. We could also add that when in Python 2.7 the support to unicodedata.category is limited, so Python 3 should be taken in account. The option to stay in Python 2.7 is to manually write down the whole category and load into a set.