# Return a specific dict from a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, object, dictionary, lambda

If I had the following code

```
attributes = []

attributes.append({'attribute': 'noir', 'group': 'coloris', 'id': '8'})
attributes.append({'attribute': 's', 'group': 'taille_textile', 'id': '29'})
attributes.append({'attribute': 'm', 'group': 'taille_textile', 'id': '24'})
attributes.append({'attribute': 'l', 'group': 'taille_textile', 'id': '25'})
attributes.append({'attribute': 'xl', 'group': 'taille_textile', 'id': '26'})
```

and I wanted to return an object of the list which contained a certain id, what would be the best way to do that?

I know that one solution would be to use the `for` loop like this

```
def getItemById(id):
    for i in attributes:
        for k,v in i.items():
            if (k == 'id' and v == id):
                return i
```

I'm sure there must be a much more elegant or efficient way to do it other than this?

Is there an opportunity to use lambdas here? would that give a performance benefit?

Comment: If you to access by `id`, why put them in a list, rather than a dictionary **keyed** by `id`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8653516/403554

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you want to return object with `'id'='29'`

This works

```
[x for x in attributes if x['id']=='29'][0]

{'attribute': 's', 'group': 'taille_textile', 'id': '29'}
```

Comment: Both soloutions are very good and much better than my own, but John you are in more need of reputation that Daniel, so I chose your answer, also it is very neat, tidy and simple

Answer (score 5):

You could use a generator:

```
next(attr for attr in attributes if attr['id'] == id_to_find)
```

Comment: I think this is the most elegant and pythonic way. :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to convert List to a pandas DataFrame.

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(attributes)

    #get all columns where id=8
    print df[df['id']=='8']

    #get specific column where id=29
    print df['attribute'][df['id']=='29']
```