# Searching for and updating a dictionary in a list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, json, list, search, dictionary

So I know this: [Python list of dictionaries search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search)

answers the first part of my question.

However, my issue is as such: I want to actually update that searched for dictionary directly, not simply retrieve it.

More specifically, I have a list of dictionaries.  The dictionaries each have a "list" key whose value is another list.  I want to update that list once I find the dictionary.

The structure for each dictionary is as such: 
    {"name": "whatever", "display":"whoever", "list": [x, y, z]}

So an example list would be:

```
[
    {"name": "whatever", "display":"whoever", "list": [x, y, z]},
    {"name": "whatever2", "display":"whoever2", "list": [x2, y2, z2]},
    {"name": "whatever3", "display":"whoever3", "list": [x3, y3, z3]}
]
```

I want to retrieve, say, the dictionary with name "whatever2" and add a2 to the "list".

What is the best way to do this?

"Best" can be however you weigh "python-ness" / "performance" / code clarity etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
L = [
    {"name": "whatever", "display":"whoever", "list": [x, y, z]},
    {"name": "whatever2", "display":"whoever2", "list": [x2, y2, z2]},
    {"name": "whatever3", "display":"whoever3", "list": [x3, y3, z3]}
]

for d in L:
    if d['name'] != 'whatever2': continue
    d['list'].append('a2')
    break  # unless you could have multiple dictionaries in your list with the same name
```