# Extract value from complex list of decoy/fake dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to extract the arrival time values from the following, which appears to be a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'arrival': {'time': 1508791028L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508791028L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508790596L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508790596L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508791744L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508791744L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508792223L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508792223L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508793450L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508793450L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508792591L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508792591L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508794110L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508794110L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508794740L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508794740L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508788421L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508788421L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508788919L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508788919L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508789417L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508789417L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508790287L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508790287L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508790347L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508790347L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508791330L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508791330L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508791799L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508791799L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508792447L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508792447L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508793300L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508793300L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508793840L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508793840L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508794380L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508794380L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508794800L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508794800L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508795220L},
  'departure': {'time': 1508795220L},
  'schedule_relationship': 0,
  'stop_id': u'D03N'}]
```

However, when I started to try and understand the structure of the list with a simple:

```
for i in in_dict:
    print i
    print "************************"
```

I got an output like this:

```
[{'arrival': {'time': 1508791028L},

************************
  'departure': {'time': 1508791028L},

************************
  'schedule_relationship': 0,

************************
  'stop_id': u'D03N'},

************************
 {'arrival': {'time': 1508790596L},

************************
  'departure': {'time': 1508790596L},
```

That output suggests to me that the elements in the list are possibly not really dictionaries (for example "{'arrival': {'time': 1508790596L}" seems like it needs another "}" to be structured correctly).

My primary question is what is the best way to extract the arrival times from this data?  My secondary question is, is this actually a  list of dictionaries or just a list of items that happen to share a resemblance with a list of dictionaries?

Comment: yeah, your "dict" is a list of lines. You probably read a file line by line, not using `json` or `ast.literal_eval` like you should have done.

Comment: so it's a list of pure strings, right?

Comment: This does look like "record" orientation of json except that we could use more info as to where your obtaining it, how it's stored, etc

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I was worried about that, thanks.

Comment: @BradSolomon it's NYC transit GTFS data.  If it was presented as json this entire enterprise would be much, much easier.  That is a string - I think I'm just going to end up with a regex search because the data is almost structured.

Comment: But ... do you have it as a variable?  As a text file? It looks precisely like json.

Comment: I ask because it's unclear how 1508791028L, 1508791028L are formatted like they are, without surrounding quotes

Comment: It is a file outputted from the "more efficient way" here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514274/extract-elements-from-complex-list-of-lists-and-dictionaries-in-python  and then loaded in to a new testing script as a file.

Comment: @BradSolomon ah I understand why you asked that. In saving the dictionary to a file I screwed up the entire structure.  Thanks!

Comment: @mweinberg You know you can call json.loads(my_var) on a string to get it as a python json object right? That looks like it would handle pretty much everything...

Comment: [`pd.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) with `orient='records'` may also be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

I created this fake dictionary by writing an existing dictionary to a file with:

```
with open('small_list.txt', 'wt') as out:
     pprint(small_list, stream=out)
```

and then importing the small_list.txt file into a simple python script to try and play with it without the rest of the script getting in the way.  However, as @bradsolomon has helped me realize in the comments, in writing the file in that way I totally borked the structure.  This created the decoy dictionary.  Therefore, the answer to this question is probably  "don't save a list of dictionaries with stream=out" or something similar.