# Python .Index of a Multidimentional Array

Tags: python

```
arrrSample =

 {'art_other_country_names': None, 
  'pk_ba_country_id': 186,
  'sin_active': 1,
  'txt_remarks': '',
  'vhr_common_country_name': 'Uzbekistan',
  'vhr_formal_country_name': 'Republic of Uzbekistan',
  'vhr_nationality': '',
  'vhr_short_country_name': '',
  'vhr_transaction_currency_code': 'UZS'},


 {'art_other_country_names': None,
  'pk_ba_country_id': 185,
  'sin_active': 1,
  'txt_remarks': '',
  'vhr_common_country_name': 'Uruguay',
  'vhr_formal_country_name': 'Oriental Republic of Uruguay',
  'vhr_nationality': '',
  'vhr_short_country_name': '',
  'vhr_transaction_currency_code': 'UYU'},


 {'art_other_country_names': None,
  'pk_ba_country_id': 184,
  'sin_active': 1,
  'txt_remarks': '',
  'vhr_common_country_name': 'United States',
  'vhr_formal_country_name': 'United States of America',
  'vhr_nationality': '',
  'vhr_short_country_name': '',
  'vhr_transaction_currency_code': 'USD'},
```

This is the sample of data i get from database. **How do i find the index in a single statement?**

Eg if the nationality of the third entry is updated i require something like this:

`arrrSample[index]['vhr_nationality'] ="American"`

How do I find the index? I have the value `'pk_ba_country_id': 184` with me 
which is `arrrSample[2]['pk_ba_country_id'] =184`.

How do I find this index 2 from 184 without looping?

I need to find index from the value, I do not wish to use a loop the array as the database can contain large data .

Comment: What you're defining there isn't a multidimensional array. You're assigning multiple dictionaries to one variable, which (I think) will result in a tuple. You'll probably need to explain what you're doing before anyone can help you. See [Python list of dictionaries search](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8653516/1288) for an example of how to define and search in a list of dictionaries.

Comment: You do not have a multidimensional array, as it is normally understood in Python to mean a `numpy.ndarray`, or *perhaps* a nested list. Your example "array" is not an array, it would give a syntax error. Assuming you have a *list of dictionaries*, then there is no way to find that index without looping, even if it is at least once to build an map from values of interest to indices.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your target is something like this (`arrrSample` was not correctly formed)?

```
arrrSample =[{'art_other_country_names': None,'pk_ba_country_id': 186,
  'sin_active': 1,
  'txt_remarks': '',
  'vhr_common_country_name': 'Uzbekistan',
  'vhr_formal_country_name': 'Republic of Uzbekistan',
  'vhr_nationality': '',
  'vhr_short_country_name': '',
  'vhr_transaction_currency_code': 'UZS'},
 {'art_other_country_names': None,
  'pk_ba_country_id': 185,
  'sin_active': 1,
  'txt_remarks': '',
  'vhr_common_country_name': 'Uruguay',
  'vhr_formal_country_name': 'Oriental Republic of Uruguay',
  'vhr_nationality': '',
  'vhr_short_country_name': '',
  'vhr_transaction_currency_code': 'UYU'},
 {'art_other_country_names': None,
  'pk_ba_country_id': 184,
  'sin_active': 1,
  'txt_remarks': '',
  'vhr_common_country_name': 'United States',
  'vhr_formal_country_name': 'United States of America',
  'vhr_nationality': '',
  'vhr_short_country_name': '',
  'vhr_transaction_currency_code': 'USD'}]

for data in arrrSample:
     if data['pk_ba_country_id'] == 184:
        print(data['vhr_common_country_name'])
```