# How to access each element of a sql query returned to python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The stock returns the stocks owned by the user. I want to pass a function lookup() on each stock returned to get the price of the stock. How will I do it since the query returns multiple rows?

```
rows = "SELECT * FROM :p1 ORDER BY id"
db.execute(rows,{'p1':str(session['user_id'])})
rows = db.fetchall()
stock = rows[0]['symbol']
share = rows[0]['shares']
price = []
```

Comment: An example of the returned data would be beneficial.

Comment: I myself am not very sure how the data is returned that's why I'm having this problem

Comment: I know a few of these types of things return data in very odd manners, and it sounds like the data may contain somewhat personal information, you might need to do some digging and figure out the structure, or at least remove personal data and post the structure.

Comment: Are you just asking about iterating through the results? Could you use `for row in rows:`?

Comment: Not able to understand your question. Can't `join` work for you in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say if this is what you're looking for but sounds like you're looking for a way to [search a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search).

```
>>> rows = [{'symbol': 'APPL', 'shares':1000},{'symbol': 'GE', 'shares': 2000},{'symbol': 'TWTR', 'shares': 5000}]
>>> def lookup(rows, stock):
...    results = [row for row in rows if row["symbol"] == stock]
...    return results
... 
>>> lookup(rows, 'APPL')
[{'symbol': 'APPL', 'shares': 1000}]
```