# Find Dict in List of Dicts Based on Incomplete Information About Wanted Dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Assume a list of dicts, e.g., the following:

```
a = {'key': 5705435, 'key2': 1, 'data': 'data'}
b = {'key': 2345435, 'key2': 1, 'data': 'data'}
c = {'key': 9155435, 'key2': 2, 'data': 'data'}
data = [a,b,c]
```

I want to get a dict from that list that matches a given key (e.g. return dict with `key == 2345435` or return dict where `key == 9155435 and key2 == 2`). Obviously I can iterate through the list and compare the key attributes like below.

```
def get_dict_by_key(data): 
    for el in data:
        if el['key'] == 2345435:
            return el
    return None
```

Is there another method to do this (without explicitly iterating through the list)? Are there some predefined methods, like for example `list.index(element)`, where I can pass into **incomplete information about the dict** I'm looking for?

Comment: there is no secret ingredient.. :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search

Comment: @SarthakNegi, There is an (IMO, critical) difference between that target question and this one, which is that this one has a (potentially unique) `key`, which could enable restructuring data / Pandas to perform many queries in O(1) time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no pre-defined methods with a list of dictionaries: you have to iterate manually. You can do so via `next` and a generator expression:

```
mydict = next((x for x in data if x['key'] == 2345435), None)
```

But your function is sufficient, and will likely be more efficient. Note `return None` is redundant, this is assumed if `return` is not met.

The O(1) time indexing capabilities you are looking for are possible by restructuring your data, e.g. a dictionary or dictionaries indexed by key, or by using a custom class.

If you can use a 3rd party library, Pandas accepts a list of dictionaries directly:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('key')
```

This gives:

```
print(df)

         data  key2
key                
5705435  data     1
2345435  data     1
9155435  data     2
```

Accessing an index label gives a series mapping:

```
print(df.loc[2345435])

data    data
key2       1
Name: 2345435, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a generator expression.

```
>>> next((d for d  in data if d.get('key') == 2345435), None)
{'data': 'data', 'key': 2345435, 'key2': 1}
```

There is no special filtering function in the standard library that does this job which I am aware of. At some level there must be a loop, because you want to do an operation *for* (potentially) every item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can the builtin `all` with a nested list comprehension. Store your desired keys in another dictionary:

```
a = {'key': 5705435, 'key2': 1, 'data': 'data'}
b = {'key': 2345435, 'key2': 1, 'data': 'data'}
c = {'key': 9155435, 'key2': 2, 'data': 'data'}
data = [a,b,c]

criteria = { 'key' : 9155435, 'key2' : 2} 

result = [x for x in data if all([value == x[key] for key,value in criteria.items()])]
```

This will return just dictionary `c` whereas the following:

```
 # returns a & b 
criteria = { 'key2' : 1} 
result = [x for x in data if all([value == x[key] for key,value in criteria.items()])]

# returns a, b & c
criteria = { 'data: 'data' } 
result = [x for x in data if all([value == x[key] for key,value in criteria.items()])]
```