# Lookup a value in a list of dictionaries efficiently

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lookup

I have a list of dictionaries as

```
x = [{'name': 'attack', 'value': 10}, {'name': 'attack_side', 'value': 12}, ..., \
{'name': 'goals', 'value': 5}, ........]
```

How can I efficiently determine whether or not the list has a dictionary with `dic['name']` is `'goals'` for example?

A solution:

```
value = None
for dic in x:
        if dic['name'] == 'goals':
            value = int(dic['value'])
            break
```

The list `x` is a stats for a football player. So, a player that have not scored any goal will not have a dictionary with `dic['name']` is `'goals'`.

`playerStats = [....]`, each element in `playerStats` has similar form of `x`, but may not have a dictionary with goals value.

*There will be around 800 lookups*

---

An actual solution using @ggorlen's answer

```
import numpy
import time

playerStats = numpy.load("/home/asus/Arief_tempo/others/Python/PL_data/players_stats.npy").item()
playerGoals = {}

a = time.perf_counter()
for name in playerStats.keys():
    lookup = {d['name']: d['value'] for d in playerStats[name]['stats']}
    try:        
        playerGoals[name] = int(lookup['goals'])
    except:
        playerGoals[name] = 0

print(time.perf_counter() - a)
```

---

Here is an actual example of an element in `playerStats`, the `x` I mentioned above can be associated to `playerStats['Mohamed Salah']['stats']`, the `'id'` won't be used here. He has 'goals', but other players may not hace 'goals' as key.

```
playerStats['Mohamed Salah']
{'id': 5178.0, 'stats': [{'name': 'accurate_back_zone_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_back_zone_pass', 'value': 70.0}, {'name': 'accurate_chipped_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_chipped_pass', 'value': 10.0}, {'name': 'accurate_corners_intobox', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_corners_intobox', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'accurate_cross', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_cross', 'value': 11.0}, {'name': 'accurate_cross_nocorner', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_cross_nocorner', 'value': 5.0}, {'name': 'accurate_flick_on', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_flick_on', 'value': 5.0}, {'name': 'accurate_freekick_cross', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_freekick_cross', 'value': 0.0}, {'name': 'accurate_fwd_zone_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_fwd_zone_pass', 'value': 377.0}, {'name': 'accurate_layoffs', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_layoffs', 'value': 19.0}, {'name': 'accurate_long_balls', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_long_balls', 'value': 7.0}, {'name': 'accurate_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_pass', 'value': 436.0}, {'name': 'accurate_through_ball', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_through_ball', 'value': 8.0}, {'name': 'accurate_throws', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: accurate_throws', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'aerial_lost', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: aerial_lost', 'value': 32.0}, {'name': 'aerial_won', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: aerial_won', 'value': 9.0}, {'name': 'appearances', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: appearances', 'value': 21.0}, {'name': 'assist_penalty_won', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: assist_penalty_won', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'attempted_tackle_foul', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: attempted_tackle_foul', 'value': 5.0}, {'name': 'attempts_conceded_ibox', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: attempts_conceded_ibox', 'value': 95.0}, {'name': 'attempts_conceded_obox', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: attempts_conceded_obox', 'value': 61.0}, {'name': 'attempts_ibox', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: attempts_ibox', 'value': 50.0}, {'name': 'attempts_obox', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: attempts_obox', 'value': 19.0}, {'name': 'att_assist_openplay', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_assist_openplay', 'value': 34.0}, {'name': 'att_assist_setplay', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_assist_setplay', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'att_bx_centre', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_bx_centre', 'value': 23.0}, {'name': 'att_bx_left', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_bx_left', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'att_bx_right', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_bx_right', 'value': 10.0}, {'name': 'att_cmiss_high', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_cmiss_high', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'att_cmiss_left', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_cmiss_left', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'att_cmiss_right', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_cmiss_right', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'att_fastbreak', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_fastbreak', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'att_freekick_total', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_freekick_total', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'att_goal_high_centre', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_goal_high_centre', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'att_goal_high_left', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_goal_high_left', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'att_goal_low_centre', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_goal_low_centre', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'att_goal_low_left', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_goal_low_left', 'value': 5.0}, {'name': 'att_goal_low_right', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_goal_low_right', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'att_hd_target', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_hd_target', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'att_hd_total', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_hd_total', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'att_ibox_blocked', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_ibox_blocked', 'value': 7.0}, {'name': 'att_ibox_goal', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_ibox_goal', 'value': 13.0}, {'name': 'att_ibox_miss', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_ibox_miss', 'value': 12.0}, {'name': 'att_ibox_target', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_ibox_target', 'value': 18.0}, {'name': 'att_lf_goal', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_lf_goal', 'value': 11.0}, {'name': 'att_lf_target', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_lf_target', 'value': 11.0}, {'name': 'att_lf_total', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_lf_total', 'value': 56.0}, {'name': 'att_lg_centre', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_lg_centre', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'att_miss_high', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_miss_high', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'att_miss_high_left', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_miss_high_left', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'att_miss_high_right', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_miss_high_right', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'att_miss_left', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_miss_left', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'att_miss_right', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_miss_right', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'att_obox_blocked', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_obox_blocked', 'value': 10.0}, {'name': 'att_obox_miss', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_obox_miss', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'att_obox_target', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_obox_target', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'att_obx_centre', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_obx_centre', 'value': 16.0}, {'name': 'att_obx_right', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_obx_right', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'att_one_on_one', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_one_on_one', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'att_openplay', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_openplay', 'value': 58.0}, {'name': 'att_pen_goal', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_pen_goal', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'att_rf_goal', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_rf_goal', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'att_rf_target', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_rf_target', 'value': 7.0}, {'name': 'att_rf_total', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_rf_total', 'value': 10.0}, {'name': 'att_setpiece', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_setpiece', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'att_sv_high_centre', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_sv_high_centre', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'att_sv_high_left', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_sv_high_left', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'att_sv_low_centre', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_sv_low_centre', 'value': 8.0}, {'name': 'att_sv_low_left', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_sv_low_left', 'value': 5.0}, {'name': 'att_sv_low_right', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: att_sv_low_right', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'backward_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: backward_pass', 'value': 151.0}, {'name': 'ball_recovery', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: ball_recovery', 'value': 61.0}, {'name': 'big_chance_created', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: big_chance_created', 'value': 13.0}, {'name': 'big_chance_missed', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: big_chance_missed', 'value': 11.0}, {'name': 'big_chance_scored', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: big_chance_scored', 'value': 8.0}, {'name': 'blocked_cross', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: blocked_cross', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'blocked_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: blocked_pass', 'value': 25.0}, {'name': 'blocked_scoring_att', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: blocked_scoring_att', 'value': 17.0}, {'name': 'challenge_lost', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: challenge_lost', 'value': 5.0}, {'name': 'clean_sheet', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: clean_sheet', 'value': 9.0}, {'name': 'corner_taken', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: corner_taken', 'value': 23.0}, {'name': 'crosses_18yard', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: crosses_18yard', 'value': 8.0}, {'name': 'crosses_18yardplus', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: crosses_18yardplus', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'dispossessed', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: dispossessed', 'value': 72.0}, {'name': 'draws', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: draws', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'duel_lost', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: duel_lost', 'value': 143.0}, {'name': 'duel_won', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: duel_won', 'value': 80.0}, {'name': 'effective_blocked_cross', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: effective_blocked_cross', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'effective_clearance', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: effective_clearance', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'effective_head_clearance', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: effective_head_clearance', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'final_third_entries', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: final_third_entries', 'value': 36.0}, {'name': 'fouled_final_third', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: fouled_final_third', 'value': 12.0}, {'name': 'fouls', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: fouls', 'value': 15.0}, {'name': 'freekick_cross', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: freekick_cross', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'fwd_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: fwd_pass', 'value': 114.0}, {'name': 'game_started', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: game_started', 'value': 20.0}, {'name': 'goals', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: goals', 'value': 13.0}, {'name': 'goals_conceded', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: goals_conceded', 'value': 9.0}, {'name': 'goals_conceded_ibox', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: goals_conceded_ibox', 'value': 9.0}, {'name': 'goals_openplay', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: goals_openplay', 'value': 9.0}, {'name': 'goal_assist', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: goal_assist', 'value': 7.0}, {'name': 'goal_assist_deadball', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: goal_assist_deadball', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'goal_assist_intentional', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: goal_assist_intentional', 'value': 7.0}, {'name': 'goal_assist_openplay', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: goal_assist_openplay', 'value': 5.0}, {'name': 'goal_assist_setplay', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: goal_assist_setplay', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'goal_fastbreak', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: goal_fastbreak', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'hand_ball', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: hand_ball', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'head_clearance', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: head_clearance', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'head_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: head_pass', 'value': 25.0}, {'name': 'interception', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: interception', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'interception_won', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: interception_won', 'value': 4.0}, {'name': 'leftside_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: leftside_pass', 'value': 216.0}, {'name': 'long_pass_own_to_opp', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: long_pass_own_to_opp', 'value': 13.0}, {'name': 'long_pass_own_to_opp_success', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: long_pass_own_to_opp_success', 'value': 10.0}, {'name': 'losses', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: losses', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'mins_played', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: mins_played', 'value': 1759.0}, {'name': 'offtarget_att_assist', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: offtarget_att_assist', 'value': 14.0}, {'name': 'ontarget_att_assist', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: ontarget_att_assist', 'value': 30.0}, {'name': 'ontarget_scoring_att', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: ontarget_scoring_att', 'value': 34.0}, {'name': 'open_play_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: open_play_pass', 'value': 556.0}, {'name': 'overrun', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: overrun', 'value': 7.0}, {'name': 'passes_left', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: passes_left', 'value': 47.0}, {'name': 'passes_right', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: passes_right', 'value': 119.0}, {'name': 'penalty_won', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: penalty_won', 'value': 3.0}, {'name': 'pen_area_entries', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: pen_area_entries', 'value': 93.0}, {'name': 'poss_lost_all', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: poss_lost_all', 'value': 323.0}, {'name': 'poss_lost_ctrl', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: poss_lost_ctrl', 'value': 323.0}, {'name': 'poss_won_att_3rd', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: poss_won_att_3rd', 'value': 20.0}, {'name': 'poss_won_def_3rd', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: poss_won_def_3rd', 'value': 14.0}, {'name': 'poss_won_mid_3rd', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: poss_won_mid_3rd', 'value': 27.0}, {'name': 'put_through', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: put_through', 'value': 25.0}, {'name': 'rightside_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: rightside_pass', 'value': 92.0}, {'name': 'shot_fastbreak', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: shot_fastbreak', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'shot_off_target', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: shot_off_target', 'value': 18.0}, {'name': 'successful_final_third_passes', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: successful_final_third_passes', 'value': 261.0}, {'name': 'successful_open_play_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: successful_open_play_pass', 'value': 419.0}, {'name': 'successful_put_through', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: successful_put_through', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'total_att_assist', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_att_assist', 'value': 44.0}, {'name': 'total_back_zone_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_back_zone_pass', 'value': 82.0}, {'name': 'total_chipped_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_chipped_pass', 'value': 30.0}, {'name': 'total_clearance', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_clearance', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'total_contest', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_contest', 'value': 61.0}, {'name': 'total_corners_intobox', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_corners_intobox', 'value': 20.0}, {'name': 'total_cross', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_cross', 'value': 36.0}, {'name': 'total_cross_nocorner', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_cross_nocorner', 'value': 16.0}, {'name': 'total_distance_in_m', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_distance_in_m', 'value': 10282.4443359375}, {'name': 'total_fastbreak', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_fastbreak', 'value': 9.0}, {'name': 'total_final_third_passes', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_final_third_passes', 'value': 363.0}, {'name': 'total_flick_on', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_flick_on', 'value': 13.0}, {'name': 'total_fwd_zone_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_fwd_zone_pass', 'value': 527.0}, {'name': 'total_launches', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_launches', 'value': 2.0}, {'name': 'total_layoffs', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_layoffs', 'value': 23.0}, {'name': 'total_long_balls', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_long_balls', 'value': 15.0}, {'name': 'total_offside', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_offside', 'value': 18.0}, {'name': 'total_pass', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_pass', 'value': 573.0}, {'name': 'total_pull_back', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_pull_back', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'total_scoring_att', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_scoring_att', 'value': 69.0}, {'name': 'total_sub_off', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_sub_off', 'value': 6.0}, {'name': 'total_sub_on', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_sub_on', 'value': 1.0}, {'name': 'total_tackle', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_tackle', 'value': 10.0}, {'name': 'total_through_ball', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_through_ball', 'value': 11.0}, {'name': 'total_throws', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: total_throws', 'value': 5.0}, {'name': 'touches', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: touches', 'value': 957.0}, {'name': 'touches_in_opp_box', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: touches_in_opp_box', 'value': 165.0}, {'name': 'turnover', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: turnover', 'value': 59.0}, {'name': 'unsuccessful_touch', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: unsuccessful_touch', 'value': 59.0}, {'name': 'was_fouled', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: was_fouled', 'value': 21.0}, {'name': 'wins', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: wins', 'value': 17.0}, {'name': 'won_contest', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: won_contest', 'value': 41.0}, {'name': 'won_corners', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: won_corners', 'value': 23.0}, {'name': 'won_tackle', 'additionalInfo': {}, 'description': 'Todo: won_tackle', 'value': 5.0}]}
```

Comment: What you already have is a good and efficient solution.

Comment: There is not more efficient way. List objects require O(N) time to check for containment, although, if the list is sorted, you can use bisection search to do it in logn time. You could use a dict to do it in O(1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list of dictionaries search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search)

Comment: I think it's worth asking whether you are going to look this up once, or whether you are going to do the lookup millions of times.  If it is just once, your solution (as well as the solutions posted below) are fine.  If you are going to do lots of lookups on the same data, then you should consider constructing a mapping of `name` -> value and using _that_ for your lookup table rather than the list.

Comment: @mgilson I am going to do it for many more similar lists

Comment: @AriefAnbiya -- If it isn't the same lists, then maybe you are out of luck unless you can coax the producer of these lists to give it to you in a different format.

Comment: @mgilson there will be a list of football player stats, each player's stat is also a list containing dictionaries for each type of stat (goals, assists, passes, etc), but a player with no goal will have no dictionary for goals stat

Comment: @AriefAnbiya there maybe an underlying problem with your code/app design if you're storing data like this and have to keep looking it up using this method for `more similar lists`. May I ask if you're storing it this way or are you simply parsing data from some other source?

Comment: @AriefAnbiya sounds like you should re-design your data structures, because a list of dicts is sort of the worst of both worlds

Comment: @AriefAnbiya I'm thinking a class might be a good idea here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dictionary of dictionaries offers O(1) lookup time:

```
x = [
    {'name': 'attack', 'value': 10}, 
    {'name': 'attack_side', 'value': 12},
    {'name': 'goals', 'value': 5}
]

lookup = {d['name']: d for d in x}

print(lookup['goals'])
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'goals', 'value': 5}
```

Notes:

- Use `lookup = {d['name']: d['value'] for d in x}` if you only need to retrieve the `value` key instead of the whole dictionary.
- Build the dictionary once and use it for all your lookups.
- If you're only doing one lookup, you already have the optimal solution.
- There must be no duplicate `name` keys.

Comment: @ggorlen your code works fine, and take up `0.04325622000033036` seconds

Comment: I am doing for about 800 lookups, since there are around 800 players

Comment: This is the way to go, then. Building one dictionary and doing 800 lookups on it should give you a huge performance boost. Your post seems to indicate that each player has a different list, though, so you'll need to [post the full scenario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and describe how many lookups are being done on each sub-list if that's the case.

Comment: No, there are about 800 players, for each player..I will lookup for a dictionary with `'goals'`. Each player has a list similar to `x`

Comment: All right, so that means you're only doing one lookup for each `x`? Then don't bother making a dictionary.

Comment: I think better to say that 'each player is associated with list similar of `x`'

Comment: I'm thinking this is likely an x-y problem. You're asking how to perform fast list lookups but it sounds like you might need to redesign your application to store data in lookup tables from the start.

Comment: @AriefAnbiya are you doing anything else with the data or are you just looking up the number of goals for each player?

Comment: @AriefAnbiya also, are you making this list of player stats because if you are then this is pretty bad design. You might have to reconsider your application design

Comment: @YangK I scraped this data. Not going to make an app of it, only for analysis. thanks

Comment: The edit you made to your post is not how I intended this to be used. You're only doing one lookup on the dict, which makes no sense.

Comment: @AriefAnbiya if you had scraped this data, you should have found a better way to store it rather than putting multiple dictionaries in a list with each list pertaining to one player.

Comment: @YangK did not put it that way, it was like that after scraping using Python

Comment: mind providing a link to the scraped data to check if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: @ggorlen , the `playerStats[name]['stats']` is `x`. And I am looping over all the players (`playerStats[name]` is a dictionary `{'id': ..., 'stats': x_like}`)

Comment: Yeah I'm seconding Yang K. Post the scraped data link and show us exactly how you're using it. What you have here is highly suspicious.

Comment: @AriefAnbiya Thanks, but that's not what we're asking for. The problem here is that all of your data is being put into containers that are not conducive to lookups. If you give us your original data source, the raw data (API, URL, database, whatever), we can determine if there is a way to build these structures for quicker lookups right from the beginning. Once the data is in lists, your hands are tied and you're stuck looping over them.

Comment: The url is https://www.premierleague.com/players/  .  But right now I intend to know best way to lookup in the current structure.

Comment: I think I know what your answer means, you want the dictionary to be restructured from `{'name': 'goals', ...}`  to just `{'goals': value}` to make it easier to access the values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186213/discussion-between-ggorlen-and-arief-anbiya).

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

#### Code:

```
goals = next((d for d in data if d['name'] == 'goals'), None)
```

This uses a generator expression to look through the list, and returns the first matching instance, or `None` if nothing matches.

#### Test Code:

```
data = [
    {'name': 'attack', 'value': 10},
    {'name': 'attack_side', 'value': 12},
    {'name': 'goals', 'value': 5}
]

goals = next((d for d in data if d['name'] == 'goals'), None)
print(goals)

no_goals = next((d for d in data if d['name'] == 'no_goals'), None)
print(no_goals)
```

#### Results:

```
{'name': 'goals', 'value': 5}
None
```

Comment: How is this "more efficient"? This is probably *slower* although the same time complexity

Comment: Why probably slower?

Comment: Although it is more condensed, seems more slower rather than efficient

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, In my quick tests, for a list of any size (len > 30) the generator in this case is definitely faster.

Comment: I'd be curious to see these tests. How about `len = 10,000?` If generators were faster than plain old loops with `break`, it seems like we'd have dumped loops long ago.

Comment: Yeah, can't reproduce. Looping over a list is always (negligibly) faster.

Comment: With the searched for element at position 10000, the loop takes almost twice as long to find it.  Let me clean up my code and add to post...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, Me being in error is most certainly possible. I am using the OPs code...  But the timing maybe fishy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48958217/6243352 has a speed test that might be relevant. Shows LC as faster than gen as faster than regular loop. I'm not convinced just yet.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, timing was suspect.  Using timeit, the generator appears to be about the same performance for the looping, but is slower to setup.  At somewhere between 1000 and 10000 elements the timings are the same. but shorter than that, the loop wins...  Thanks for the insights.

Comment: Thanks. But I thought `generator` is known to be fast in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a different approach: convert the list of dictionary in a different format, precisely in a dict:

```
x = [{'name': 'attack', 'value': 10}, {'name': 'attack_side', 'value': 12},{'name': 'goals', 'value': 5}]

player_x = { ability['name']: ability['value'] for ability in x }
#=> {'attack': 10, 'attack_side': 12, 'goals': 5}
```

Then it is easy to get:

```
print(player_x.get('attack', None)) #=> 10
print(player_x.get('whathever', None)) #=> None
```

Or also:

```
for ability in player_x.keys():
  print(ability, player_x[ability])

# attack 10
# attack_side 12
# goals 5
```