# Search key on a listed dictionary that contains a partial query

Tags: python, list, dictionary, search

I want to output all the dictionary items in a list that contain a partial query on one of it's keys.

Considering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search), I want to achieve something similar but, from the following list:

```
people = [
{"name": "Pamela", "age": 9}
{"name": "Tom", "age": 10},
{"name": "Mark", "age": 5},
{"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
]
```

Searching for `"Pam"`, I want to get both of these entries:

```
{"name": "Pamela", "age": 9},
{"name": "Pam", "age": 7}
```

Since I would like to search for different keys in the dictionary, based on user preference, I think this is the best solution I find in the mentioned thread:

```
def search(db, key, value):
    for item in db:
        if value in item[key]: # This is the line i'm having trouble with
            return item
```

However, the command `print(search(people, 'name', 'Pam'))` will only output 
`{"name": "Pam", "age": 7}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I think I found a solution. The function was indeed getting both results but `return item` was only returning the last item viewed by the `for` loop and, as expected, the `print` statement only showed that. Here is the code I'm using if someone is having the same problem:

```
def search(db, key, value):
    result = []
    for item in db:
        if value in item[key]:
            result.append(item)
```

It's just a matter of instantiating an empty list and appending to it the items that pass. I feel a bit dumb and proud at the same time now.