# python: lookup in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the value is a list of dictionaries:

```
{ 'client1':
   [
     { 'id': 123, 'name': 'test1', 'number': 777 },
     { 'id': 321, 'name': 'test2', 'number': 888 },
     { 'id': 456, 'name': 'test3', 'number': 999 }
   ],
...
}
```

and there is lots of entries keys by `clientX`.

Now, in order to fetch entry with e.g. `name == test2`, I loop through the list and check for `name` value, something like this:

```
for l in d['client']:
   if 'test2' in l['name']:
     # process the entry
...
```

Is there a shorter/compact way to do such a lookup?

Comment: YOu say you want to fetch entry with `name == test2` but in the code you write `'test2' in l['name']` which is a different thing. First is equality, second is inclusion. So what do you really want to fetch?

Comment: This expression is the simplest expression for **linear search**. In my suggestion, you can add a break statement at the end of 'if-else clause' to make it run faster

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list of dictionaries search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search)

Comment: @nadapez, _YOu say you want to fetch entry with name == test2 but in the code you write 'test2' in l['name'] which is a different thing. First is equality, second is inclusion._ I'm newbie in python, thanks for correcting me. `in` returns `True` if a sequence with the specified value is present in object, correct? In my case `l['name']` is a string, so both `==` and `in` would yield `True`. Am I wrong?

Comment: `'test2' in l['name']` would  also be `true` if `l[name]` is `'test22'` which is incorrect

Comment: @nadapez, I see, that makes a huge difference. So `in` doesn't perform an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of list comprehension:

```
if "test2" in [l["name"] for l in d["client"]]:
    # process the entry
```

This generates the whole list of names for you to compare to, and this does shorten your code by one line while also making it slightly more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want something like this.

```
for v in d.values():
    item = next((x for x in v if x["name"] == "test2"), None)
    item and print("found: ", item)
```

and as you are in **python2** so instated of `item and print("found: ", item)`

```
if item:
    print "found: ", item
```

Comment: What is `item and print("found: ", item)` ?

Comment: it checks if item is not `None` then it prints the value. the `and` looks to the `item` if it was **True** it will go for the other side, if was **Not True** it won't.