# Python searching key returning values from list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm missing something and its driving me bananas,. For some reason, the lookup to the `aliases` list of dicts is not working.

```py
import urllib.parse


def parse_source_from_url(url):
    # Clean up the url
    parse_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(url.strip().replace('\n', ''))
    
    # Parse the interesting parts
    url = parse_url.netloc.split('.')
    
    # Words to omit
    keywords = ['feeds', 'com']
    
    # Determine which url words are not keywords to omit
    feed_source = [u for u in url if u not in keywords][0]
    
    # Map out aliases as needed
    aliases = [
        {'feed_source': 'example', 'alias': 'good'},
        {'feed_source': 'feedburner', 'alias': 'notgood'}]
    
    # Select alias if feed_source is shown in list of dict
    # This is where the problem is
    feed_source = [
        a['alias']
        if a['feed_source'] == feed_source
        else feed_source
        for a in aliases]
    
    # Return only the aliased name
    return feed_source[0]

urls = ['https://feeds.example.com/', 'https://feeds.feedburner.com/']

for u in urls:
    test = parse_source_from_url(u)
    print(test)
```

**Results:**

- The first result is correct ("example" aliased "good") but the second URL is incorrect.
- "feedburner" should be aliased as "notgood"

```
good
feedburner
```

**Tried:**

- The method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search) using `next()` and the `get()` methods.
- Same issue

Comment: I'm confused what `feed_source` is supposed to be. I have the impression you are using the same variable name for at least 2 different things.

Comment: Initially, its the list of `.netloc.split('.')` part of the url (Ex. `[feeds, feedburner, com]`). Then the alias check. If feed_source should be aliased, then get the 'alias' from the dict with the corresponding 'feed_source', Otherwise, leave it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You kinda miss the `if` placement in your loop. Now your `feed_source` list contains as much records as `aliases` list. And all of them are equal `feed_source` except eventually the one that has alias, but you takes first of it anyway.

Correct code should be:

```
    aliased = [a["alias"] for a in aliases if a["feed_source"] == feed_source]
    return aliased[0] if aliased else feed_source
```

So `aliased` has maximum one element now. If it, it's alias, if not (so `aliased` is empty) you just return `feed_source`

And one hint - if your `aliases` element always have two keys, maybe you could just use dict:

```
aliases = {'example': 'good', 'feedburner': 'notgood'}
```

Comment: Thank you for putting eye on the code. I'm new to list comprehensions. I like your idea for renaming the variable to `aliased`. I don't quite understand why putting `else feed_source` as part of the `return` vs. the original list comp. But its working! I'll study.

Comment: Because where there is no `alias` for `feed_source` the `aliased` list will be empty and probably you don't want to return emtpy list here.

Comment: I mean, it depends. You can always add to `aliases` record like {"feed_source": "without_alias", "alias": "without_alias"}

Comment: Anyway, think about my last hint I edited - it will make your code significantly easier.