How to check the occurrences of a dictionary key in another list and create new output
I have a list and a dictionary like this:
mydict = {
    'some-id-string1': {'name': 'Saeed1', 'phone': '+989307333730', 'id': 'abc'},
    'some-id-string2': {'name': 'Saeed2', 'phone': '+989307333731', 'id': 'def'},
    'some-id-string3': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333732', 'id': 'ghi'},
    'some-id-string4': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333733', 'id': 'jkl'},
    'some-id-string5': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333730', 'id': 'abc'},
    'some-id-string6': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333730', 'id': 'abc'},
    'some-id-string7': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333731', 'id': 'def'},

}
mylist = [
    {'id': 'abc', 'name': 'some_name1'},
    {'id': 'def', 'name': 'some_name2'},
    {'id': 'ghi', 'name': 'some_name3'},
]

I'm going to check if the id value of the mydict matches mylist and add the name of mylist to mydict. If that doesn't exist there, I'm going to have two output (because I'm not sure currently to keep which one, so I'm going to have both to decide later):
Expected output 1 if name exists and to add NOT_FOUND for the ones not having corresponding name:
newmydict1 = {
    'some-id-string1': {'name': 'Saeed1', 'phone': '+989307333730', 'id': 'abc', 'id_name': 'some_name1'},
    'some-id-string2': {'name': 'Saeed2', 'phone': '+989307333731', 'id': 'def', 'id_name': 'some_name2'},
    'some-id-string3': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333732', 'id': 'ghi', 'id_name': 'some_name3'},
    'some-id-string4': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333733', 'id': 'jkl', 'id_name': 'NOT_FOUND'},
    'some-id-string5': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333730', 'id': 'abc', 'id_name': 'some_name1'},
    'some-id-string6': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333730', 'id': 'abc', 'id_name': 'some_name1'},
    'some-id-string7': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333731', 'id': 'def', 'id_name': 'some_name2'},
}

Expected output 2 if name exists and to create a new list for the ones not having corresponding name:
newmydict2 {
    'some-id-string1': {'name': 'Saeed1', 'phone': '+989307333730', 'id': 'abc', 'id_name': 'some_name1'},
    'some-id-string2': {'name': 'Saeed2', 'phone': '+989307333731', 'id': 'def', 'id_name': 'some_name2'},
    'some-id-string3': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333732', 'id': 'ghi', 'id_name': 'some_name3'},
    'some-id-string5': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333730', 'id': 'abc', 'id_name': 'some_name1'},
    'some-id-string6': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333730', 'id': 'abc', 'id_name': 'some_name1'},
    'some-id-string7': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333731', 'id': 'def', 'id_name': 'some_name2'},
}
newmydict3 = {
    'some-id-string4': {'name': 'Saeed3', 'phone': '+989307333733', 'id': 'jkl'},
}

I'm not sure what to do and what to write, because the key of mydict (I mean some-id-string) does not exist in mylist, and also some members of the mydict['id'] has more than one occurences.
I tried
new = [{
    'string_id': d, 
    'id': l['id'], 
    'id_name': l['name'], 
    'phone': mydict[d]['phone'], 
    'name': mydict[d]['name']
    } for l in mylist for d in mydict if mydict[d]['id'] == l['id']
]


You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Other than that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/search-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python for finding a dictionary by the value of a key.

@ScottHunter unfortunately I have no attempts.

@Barmar regarding the link, I think (I'm not sure BTW) I know how to search by key/value if there's one list or dict. But regarding this case I don't know.

What's the problem? Just loop through mylist, and use that technique to search for the matching element in mydict. If you know how to do something for one dict, you just repeat it for all the dicts.

@Barmar I thought before the question something like for l in mylist: mydict[l['id']], but I get KeyError: 'abc' which is I know why I'm getting it. Do you mean I should use two for loops? I'm trying to avoid using two nested loops.

@Barmar new = [{'string_id': d, 'id': l['id'], 'id_name': l['name'], 'phone': mydict[d]['phone'], 'name': mydict[d]['name']} for l in mylist for d in mydict if mydict[d]['id'] == l['id']] something like is this that I tried not to do, and to see if there are any other ways to it in one loop.

You're pretty close, but new is a list, you want a dictionary. So use a dictionary comprehension rather than a list comprehension.
newmydict2 = {key: {
    'id': l['id'], 
    'id_name': l['name'], 
    'phone': value['phone'], 
    'name': value['name']
    } for l in mylist for key, value in mydict.items() if value['id'] == l['id']
}

newmydict3 = {key: value for key, value in mydict.items() if key not in newmydict2}

Also, use mydict.items() so you can access the key and value with variables rather than repeating mydict[d].
If mylist is large, it would be more efficient to convert it to a dictionary first, rather than searching it repeatedly.
mylist_dict = {l['id']: l['name'] for l in mylist}

newmydict2 = {key: {
    'id': value['id'], 
    'id_name': mylist_dict[value['id']], 
    'phone': value['phone'], 
    'name': value['name']
    } for key, value in mydict.items() if value['id'] in mylist_dict
}

You could also convert your input to pandas dataframes, then use its merge and difference operations.

Thanks, so there should be two for loops. Am I right? The real world example's for loop would be 600 * 300 iterations. Do you think it's not a big deal in this case?

If mylist is large, it would probably be a good idea to convert it to a dictionary that uses id as the keys, rather than searching it repeatedly.

Or use pandas as I suggested at the end. It's specifically designed for processing tabular data like this efficiently.

I've added code that shows how to create and use this dictionary.
