# Best way to split strings

Tags: python, string, list, split, list-comprehension

I have a list which contains first and last names, like this one:

```
names = ["John Smith", "Rob Julian", "Eric Walls"]
```

I want to get only the first names in this list.

I achieved that by doing:

```
first_names = [n.split(" ")[0] for n in names]
```

And that gave me the wanted result.

But in my opinion this is pretty ugly, is there any better way to achieve that goal?

Comment: That's exactly what I'd write, except I'd omit the `" "`.

Comment: If you think that's ugly try doing it in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not really. Performance wise you are better off with what you have.

```
first_names = []
for n in names:
    first_names.append(n.split()[0])
```

would work, but i love list comprehension in python. I mean whats wrong with

```
first_names = [n.split()[0] for n in names]
```

For fun, you could also do the following. I would imagine if you are processing a very large list this might have the best performance. But, you might want to investigate that first.

```
first = lambda n : n.split()[0]
first_names = [first(name) for name in names]
```

to make this comprehensive, you could also use the lambda to map it.

```
first = lambda n : n.split()[0]
first_names = map(first,names)
```

Per comments, I am adding yet another way

```
from operator import itemgetter
first_names = map(itemgetter(0), map(str.split, names))
```

#### in conclusion, yes there are other ways to do it.

but your original seems to be the most preferred. If speed is an issue you may want to tinker with the others.

#### updated with time

not the most scientific, but using a list of approximaltey 3.5million names, I ran the above calling the files n0-4 and ran `time n0;time n1; time n2; time n3; time n4`
here are my results. Looks as if the original list comprehension was the fastest on my machine.

```
real    0m8.433s
user    0m7.064s
sys     0m1.288s

real    0m8.213s
user    0m6.852s
sys     0m1.300s

real    0m8.581s
user    0m7.240s
sys     0m1.264s

real    0m8.374s
user    0m7.164s
sys     0m1.140s

real    0m11.890s
user    0m10.101s
sys     0m1.672s
```

(I ran them a few times in differing orders, times were consistent.)

Comment: It's not faster, but nice try.
`In [1]: %timeit first_names = [first(name) for name in names]`
`100000 loops, best of 3: 2.81 us per loop`

`In [2]: %timeit [n.split()[0] for n in names]`
`100000 loops, best of 3: 2 us per loop`

`In [3]: %timeit map(itemgetter(0), map(str.split, names))`
`100000 loops, best of 3: 3.79 us per loop`

Comment: thanks, I was just about to run these tests myself. I think I'll refrain and fetch myself some dinner.

Comment: It's much nicer to use `operator.itemgetter(0)` instead of the `lambda`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter

Comment: Nice summary. You should also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426754/google-python-style-guide

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is awesome, but

```
first_names = [n.split()[0] for n in names]
```

is a little awesomer.

Read [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best performance would result from using an anonymous function along with the `map` function:

```
first = lambda n : n.split()[0]

first_names = map(first,names)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's *better*, but here's another approach:

```
>>> names = ["John Smith", "Rob Julian", "Eric Walls"]
>>> first = lambda x:x.split()[0]
>>> map(first, names)
['John', 'Rob', 'Eric']
```