# Modifying all the tuples in a Python list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list containing tuples with a standard format:

```
bar_list = [(bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4), (bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4), (bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4)...]
```

Though I want to iterate through each tuple in the list and for each make specific modifications such as:

```
foo0 = bar1
foo1 = get_foo(foo0) #get_foo(var) being a function
foo2 = bar2
foo3 = bar3/2
```

And then repackage the revalued tuples in another list:

```
foo_list = [(foo1, foo2, foo3), (foo1, foo2, foo3), (foo1, foo2, foo3)...]
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not just append them to a new list as you make them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
foo_list = [(get_foo(bar1), bar2, bar3/2) 
            for bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4 in bar_list]
```

---

Note, I'm assuming you meant for `foo1` to equal `get_foo(bar1)` rather than the `NameError`-raising and self-referential

```
foo1 = get_foo(foo1)
```

Comment: Thanks unutbu, worked to perfection (I ended up inserting the wrong variable, great assumption)!

Answer (score -1):

You could use `map` here:

```
def func(lis):
    bar1,bar2,bar3,bar4=lis
    foo0 = bar1
    foo1 = get_foo(foo0) #or get_foo(bar1)
    foo2 = bar2
    foo3 = bar3/2
    return foo1,foo2,foo3


bar_list = [(bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4), (bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4), (bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4)...] 

foo_list = map(func,bar_lis)
```

Comment: Great, I think you missed to return `foo0`

Comment: @eLRuLL OP's expected output has only 3 values: `(foo1,foo2,foo3)`.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice, this is perfect then.

Comment: I wouldn't say perfect .. map considered unpythonic  http://stackoverflow.com/q/5426754/674039

Comment: @wim `Unpythonic` doesn't means it is wrong and to be downvoted, and `map`,`filter` are still built-ins are py3.x. And there are cases where map outperforms LC's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map.

Comment: @downvoter The downvoting arrow says "The answer is not useful"? Please explain how this is not useful.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter in this case! Yet, I admit that I regularly downvote answers where `map` is recommended when an equivalent (and better) comprehension could be used instead.

Comment: map outperforming LCs in some special cases is a non-issue for me, I always take style over performance - if it's performance-critical code, I'll put those parts in C