# How to make a list out of a set of result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So here I defined a function in python that tells if a given number is even or odd.

Now i want to create a list with the numbers in the result as its elemets, how is that possible?

```
def even_till_n(number):
     for in range(number+1): 
        if  (i%2 == 0):
             print(i)
```

Comment: That code does not work first of all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python- How to generate new list from variable in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888880/python-how-to-generate-new-list-from-variable-in-a-loop)

Comment: Also, please use the generic [python] tag for all python questions, use a version specific tag at your discretion

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list variable and append values to it.  Then make your function return that list:

```
def even_till_n(number):
     result = list()
     for i in range(number+1): 
        if  (i%2 == 0):
             result.append(i)
     return result

# usage ...

test = even_till_n(10)
print(test)

# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list-comprehension.

```
def even_till_n(number):
    return [x for x in range(number+1) if x%2 == 0]
```

Comment: List-comprehensions are a feature of python: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python they follow are used to create lists from other iterables

Comment: If the OP doesn't even understand how construct a list, perhaps throwing a list comprehension at them isn't very helpful pedagogically.