# Why doesn't Python's filter(predicate, set) return a set?

Tags: python, list, filter, set, python-2.x

Why was Python's `filter` designed such that if you run `filter(my_predicate, some_set)`, I get back a `list` object return than a `set` object?
Are there practical cases where you would *not* want the result to be a `set`...?

Comment: Who cares? Use comprehensions. Filter is depreciated.

Comment: @JohnColeman: filter is not deprecated.

Comment: @DSM maybe not officially depreciated, but it came close: "filter and map should die and be subsumed into list comprehensions, not grow more variants." - Guido Van Rossum.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426754/google-python-style-guide

Comment: @JohnColeman: yes, about a decade ago, Guido wanted to remove them (as well as lambda).  The community fought him so hard that he had to give up.  That is not deprecation.

Comment: @DSM I agree now. I was confusing it with `reduce` (which is part of that same Lisp-like cluster of functions) which is still in the language but has been hidden in a module. I see that `filter` can be used directly. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @JohnColeman: *I* certainly care, and that's enough reason for me to want to know the answer to this question.

Comment: The reason might be the fact that lists are more inclusive. Sets _cannot_ maintain duplicates. You can always get a set from a list. But you cannot necessarily regain an original list from the corresponding set.

Answer (score 5):

You can do a set comprehension.

```
{my_predicate(x) for x in some_set}      # mapping
{x for x in some_set if my_predicate(x)} # filtering
```

such as

```
In [1]: s = set([1,2,3])

In [2]: {x%2 for x in s}
Out[2]: {0, 1}
```

Many of the "functional" functions in *Python 2* are standardized on having `list` as the output type. This was just an API choice long ago. In `itertools` many of the same "functional" functions standardize on providing a generator from which you could populate whatever data structure you'd like. And in Python 3 they are standardized on providing an iterator.

But do also note that "filtering" in Python is not like it is in some other languages, like, say Haskell. It's not considered to be a transformation *within* the context of the data structure, and you don't choose to "endow" your data structures with "filterability" by making them an instance of Functor (or whatever other similar ideas exist in other languages).

As a result, it's a common use case in Python to say something like: "Here's a set, but I just want back all of the values less than 5. I don't care about their 'set-ness' after that point cause I'm just going to do some other work on them, so just give me a ____." No need to get all crazy about preserving the context within which the values originally lived.

In a dynamic typing culture this is very reasonable. But in a static typing culture where preserving the type during transformations might matter, this would be a bit frustrating. It's really just sort of a heuristic from Python's particular perspective.

If it was really just in a very narrow context of a `set` or `tuple` then I might just write a helper function:

```
def type_preserving_filter(predicate, data):
    return type(data)(filter(predicate, data))
```

such as

```
>>> type_preserving_filter(lambda x: x > 3, set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7]))
{4, 5, 6, 7}
>>> type_preserving_filter(lambda x: x > 3, list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7]))
[4, 5, 6, 7, 7]
>>> type_preserving_filter(lambda x: x > 3, tuple([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7]))
(4, 5, 6, 7, 7)
```

which works in both Python 2.10 and Python 3.4. In Python 2 this feels a bit wasteful; constructing from the iterator in Python 3 is better.

Comment: `filter` only returns a list in Python 2.  Same with `map`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not limited to `filter()`. But the API has changed in Python 3, where `filter()` now returns an iterator instead of a list. Quoting the python documentation:

> #### [Views And Iterators Instead Of Lists](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists)
>
> Some well-known APIs no longer return lists:
>
> ...
>
> - `map()` and
>     `filter()`
>     return iterators. If you really need a list, a quick fix is e.g.
>     `list(map(...))`, but a better fix is often to use a list
>     comprehension (especially when the original code uses lambda), or
>     rewriting the code so it doesn’t need a list at all. Particularly
>     tricky is `map()` invoked for the side effects of the function; the
>     correct transformation is to use a regular for loop (since creating a
>     list would just be wasteful).

This article written by the author of Python goes into detail for reasons for dropping `filter()` in Python 3 (but this did not happen as you can see above, although the reasoning is still important.)

> #### [The fate of `reduce()` in Python 3000](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)
>
> ...
>
> I think dropping `filter()` and `map()` is pretty uncontroversial;
>   `filter(P, S)` is almost always written clearer as `[x for x in S if P(x)]`, and this has the huge advantage that the most common usages
>   involve predicates that are comparisons, e.g. `x==42`, and defining a
>   lambda for that just requires much more effort for the reader (plus
>   the lambda is slower than the list comprehension). Even more so for
>   `map(F, S)` which becomes `[F(x) for x in S]`. Of course, in many
>   cases you'd be able to use generator expressions instead.