# snmpwalk : get list of integers not string

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp

In my python script I fetch 5 OID which return each an integer 
Here my code :

```
OIDs = []
res = []

OIs.append(netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('1.3.6.1.4.1.45.1.1.4.1')))
OIs.append(netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('1.3.6.1.4.1.45.1.1.4.2')))
OIs.append(netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('1.3.6.1.4.1.45.1.1.4.3')))
OIs.append(netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('1.3.6.1.4.1.45.1.1.4.4')))
OIs.append(netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('1.3.6.1.4.1.45.1.1.3.1')))

for i in range(len(OIDs)):
    res.append(netsnmp.snmpwlak(OIDs[i], Version = 2, DestHost='192.168.0.1', Community='public'))
return res
```

`print res` return me that list :

```
[('18',), ('13',), ('1',), ('2',), ('1',)]
```

All values returned by OID are integers

**Qestion :**

How can I get a list with only integers inside, like this :

```
[18, 13, 1, 2, 1]
```

Anyone know how to solve my problem ?

Comment: Apparently, nobody knows how. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = [('18',), ('13',), ('1',), ('2',), ('1',)]
res = [int(x[0]) for x in res] ## [18, 13, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Yeah. Lesson learned. I timed both, list comprehension is more performant. +1.

Comment: @idjaw not sure about the timing but it is more pythonic and map is somewhat deprecated

Comment: Is map really deprecated? Because in Python 3 it actually returns a generator. So it seems like it's still getting love. However, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5426851/1832539 . LC ftw.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`

```
a = [('18',), ('13',), ('1',), ('2',), ('1',)]

print(map(lambda x: int(x[0]), a))
```

Output:

```
[18, 13, 1, 2, 1]
```

- EDIT*

While this works, the list comprehension is more performant. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35630604/1832539) answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[int(x[0]) for x in res]
```