# Python syntax for a map(max()) call

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I came across this particular piece of code in one of "beginner" tutorials for Python. It doesn't make logical sense, if someone can explain it to me I'd appreciate it.

```
print(list(map(max, [4,3,7], [1,9,2])))
```

I thought it would print [4,9] (by running max() on each of the provided lists and then printing max value in each list). Instead it prints [4,9,7]. Why three numbers?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map()` takes each element in turn from all sequences passed as the second and subsequent arguments. Therefore the code is equivalent to:

```
print([max(4, 1), max(3, 9), max(7, 2)])
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks, will accept as the correct answer as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 6):

You're thinking of

```
print(list(map(max, [[4,3,7], [1,9,2]])))
#                   ^                ^
```

providing *one* sequence to `map`, whose elements are `[4,3,7]` and `[1,9,2]`.

The code you've posted:

```
print(list(map(max, [4,3,7], [1,9,2])))
```

provides `[4,3,7]` and `[1,9,2]` as *separate arguments* to `map`. When `map` receives multiple sequences, it iterates over those sequences in parallel and passes corresponding elements as separate arguments to the mapped function, which is `max`.

Instead of calling

```
max([4, 3, 7])
max([1, 9, 2])
```

it calls

```
max(4, 1)
max(3, 9)
max(7, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question has been answered already, but I'd like to note that `map()` is considered obsolete in python, with [list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426754/google-python-style-guide) being used instead as they are usually more performant. Your code would be equivalent to `print([max(x) for x in [(4,1),(3,9),(7,2)]])`.

Also, [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) is an interesting article from Guido on the subject.

Comment: I wouldn't say they're obsolete. Sometimes it's better to go for the more expressive approach using `map` than writing a bunch of nested, ugly list comprehensions.

Comment: The link to article is very useful, though seems awfully dated. I'm intrigued by your comment, though, that the list comprehension would be more performant. I'd have thought that map would be easier to parallelize, while list comprehensions would necessarily have to be serialized. Unless Guido has found a way to parallelize arbitrary functions - or I am missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Most have answered OPs question as to why,
Here's how to get that output using max:

```
a = [4,3,7]
b = [1,9,2]

print(list(map(max, [a, b])))
```

gives

```
[7, 9]
```